# Qual o papel dos padrões de arquitetura em orientação a objeto?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, mvc, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, mvvm

Essa pergunta parece ter uma resposta óbvia, mas eu confesso que ainda não peguei a ideia sozinho. Estou trabalhando com orientação a objetos desde 2011, principalmente voltado para desenvolvimento web. Logo que comecei já ouvi falar sobre MVC. Quando peguei um livro de MVC pra ler ele citava muitos outros padrões de arquitetura, entre eles o MVVM e o MVP.

Mas qual o real papel desses padrões de arquitetura? Sempre que vamos fazer um projeto orientado a objetos escolhemos algum padrão pra basear ele? Claro que é possível criar um novo projeto e sair programando sem padrão nenhum, mas na prática sempre escolhe-se um padrão pra basear o projeto?

Além disso, me parece que a decisão dos padrões se baseia em última instância não no modelo de domínio mas na interface com o usuário. Digo isso porque vi o seguinte: a motivação para o MVC na web é o fato do HTTP não manter estado, o fato da interface com o usuário ser na web. O MVVM aparece em cenários onde há estado, ou seja, o fato da interface com o usuário permitir isso, e por ai vai. Como é feita essa escolha de padrão?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

O mais importante quando se trata de arquitetura de software é entender os mecanismos utilizados em cada uma das camadas, seu benefícios e impactos.

Os modelos padronizados servem como uma referência para facilitar a aprendizagem, a comunicação entre arquitetos e desenvolvedores e também como referência de boas práticas.

Por exemplo, ao invés de alguém dizer "olha, meu sistema é feito de forma que os tipos, as telas e a lógica ficam em camadas separadas", basta dizer que o sistema baseia-se no modelo MVC, embora em muitos casos isso ainda seja um tanto vago.

Quando o desenvolvedor está ciente dos modelos mais comuns e dos pontos fracos e fortes de cada um ele poderá comparar com os requisitos de um sistema e selecionar a melhor opção para atendê-los.

Ao iniciar a implementação, o desenvolvedor também poderá filtrar os frameworks e ferramentas mais adequados de acordo com o modelo que cada um suporta. Isso facilita bastante na escolha tecnológica.

Ter um ponto de partida para a arquitetura em forma de modelos de referência é muito melhor que tentar fazer tudo "do zero". Na verdade, esta é uma das diferenças entre profissionais mais experientes e os mais novatos. Os experientes, já conhecendo os padrões e boas práticas, tendem a ir mais diretamente nas melhores soluções já conhecidas para cada situação, enquanto os menos experientes tendem a querer reinventar a roda.

Answer (score 25):

Vou acrescentar uma outra abordagem ao que já foi dito.

## O que é um padrão de projeto e a [não] relação com OOP.

Padrões de arquitetura ou padrões de projeto, os famosos *design patterns*, de forma bem objetiva, tem um papel **facilitador** para executar tarefas repetitivas que já possuem soluções conhecidas que são consideradas adequadas para determinadas situações.

#### Orientação a objeto

Não precisa ter uma relação direta com orientação a objetos. Padrões de projeto estão em tudo o que você faz na programação em qualquer paradigma.

Em alguns padrões de projeto isso é mais necessário em linguagens orientadas a objetos. Os padrões servem para resolver problemas que a própria linguagem criou ou problemas que a linguagem não consegue lidar bem. Normalmente isto é feito criando **regras, modelos, receitas de código** que usados daquela forma atingem um objetivo.

## Padrões estão em todo lugar

Mas é preciso entender que existem padrões de projeto que não são assim. **Existem padrões nas bibliotecas**. O que é até melhor porque você não precisa saber como implementar este padrão de projeto, tem que saber apenas como usar as ferramentas disponíveis na biblioteca. A grosso modo apenas tem que saber como chamar e como usar o resultado de uma ou mais funções ou métodos.

Infelizmente o termo *design patterns* ficou famoso apenas para o primeiro caso. E para piorar, as pessoas acham que esses padrões famosos encontrados em livros e sites são solução para tudo. Acham que tudo pode ser resolvido com um padrão existente. Os programadores e gerentes de projeto abusam de algo consagrado porque não entendem bem o que estão fazendo. Perguntar sobre casos específicos sobre o assunto pode ir ajudando entender melhor em casos específicos.

Existe ainda uma outra forma de padrão de projeto muito comum e existente há décadas. São as **construções de linguagem**.

#### Construções de linguagem

Então, por exemplo, [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um padrão de projeto que ninguém acha que é porque está aí há tanto tempo. Raramente é ensinado como ela funciona concretamente e as pessoas não conseguem enxergá-la como um padrão, principalmente porque a linguagem disfarça bem. E fica mais complicado vender livros, palestras e consultorias de algo tão importante, mas também tão pronto para ser usado.

[Funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101) são *design patterns*, assim como métodos que já é um padrão em cima de outro padrão que está implementado em cima de diversos outros padrões. Operadores também são.

[*Statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) como  `if`, `for`, `while`, `for each`, etc. são outros exemplos.

Valores, referências, expressões, e claro, classes são todos padrões de projeto. Ninguém pensa muito como usá-los como padrão de projeto.

Tem linguagens que ensinam como implementar o padrão *observer*, tem linguagens que possuem este padrão implementados como eventos.

Quando o padrão está tão enraizado na sua mente você acha que não está usando um padrão de projeto. Eu conheço programador que não pensa mais sobre o uso do [MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/101). Aquilo é tão normal para ele que não parece ser um padrão (outros porque não entendem o que está fazendo, só "ensinaram-me assim"). Mas podemos dizer que **sempre escolhemos um padrão em tudo**.

A maioria dos padrões são muito bons quando usados no momento certo, sejam eles parte da linguagem, biblioteca ou receita de bolo.

## Como escolher um padrão

Alguns padrões são determinados ou influenciados pelas tecnologias que você escolheu. Embora nem sempre precise segui-los. É comum seguir o que foi determinado para uma tecnologia. Profissionais muito bons e com conhecimento profundo naquela tecnologia escolheram o que seria mais adequado em cada caso. Mas eles podem errar. Eles podem propor algo ótimo para a maioria dos casos mas que não seja o ideal para você em determinada situação.

#### Você pode criar um novo padrão

É possível mas é improvável que ele seja melhor do que os existentes. Claro que isto depende do que você está fazendo. Em domínios específicos pode ser que você crie um padrão que pelo menos não foi publicado como um caso conhecido e comprovado.

#### Ovo ou galinha?

Há casos que você pode determinar o melhor padrão para uma tarefa e ir à caça da tecnologia que melhor atende sua necessidade. Deveria, mas isso não é tão comum.

#### Experiência, sempre ela

Você deve aproveitar o que outros mais experientes fizeram antes ou sua experiência anterior. Deve aprender com essas experiências. Só **não deve ficar cego** e considerar que todo padrão de projeto que aparece é bom para tudo.

## Seus exemplos

#### MVC

Eu, por exemplo, nunca trabalhei ativamente com *web*, faço basicamente aplicações desktop. Sempre que posso, pelo menos mais recentemente (no passado eu usava padrões que eram bons para a necessidade da época e que nem tinham nome, mas hoje são considerados arcaicos) procuro usar MVC  (ou algo parecido) e minhas aplicações são *stateful*. Então não há uma relação direta que foi citada como uma possibilidade para seu uso. O motivo para se usar o MVC está destacado abaixo.

Hoje quase todo mundo concorda que precisa usar um **padrão de interação com o usuário que o modelo de dados precisa estar separado do comportamento que manipula a interação com o usuário**. Existem alguns padrões que fazem isto. Uso o MVC porque se adapta bem ao que eu preciso e já é bem usado com as tecnologias que tenho adotado.

MVC está muito associado com UI. Embora nada impeça de fazer de outra forma, praticamente qualquer API para UI é exposta utilizando técnicas de OOP. Provavelmente UI é a aplicação mais adequada para OOP. Portanto o padrão MVC e OOP acabam tendo uma uma relação próxima nos casos comuns.

Alguns padrões se encaixam melhor em alguns paradigmas, sendo quase inviáveis usando outro paradigma. Por outro lado alguns padrões são tão adequados a um paradigma que muitas vezes você acha que não está usando padrão algum. O paradigma impõe determinados padrões intrinsecamente, em oposição a recomendar uma receita de bolo.

#### [MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101)

Se eu for usar WPF, por exemplo, vou ver melhor como funciona o MVVM. Mas não é porque a Microsoft diz que é bom que eu vou usá-lo. Dá muito bem para usar WPF sem MVVM. Eu sei que o projeto fica mais simples se não usá-lo, e isto é uma grande vantagem. Mas ainda não sei tudo o que eu perco com isto. Certamente tem alguma perda, sei de pelo menos uma. Vou ter que fazer uma escolha. Vou contar com minha experiência. Não tem outro jeito. Por isso que você vê na internet um monte de gente amando e odiando esta tecnologia (só para ficar neste exemplo). Cada um tem uma experiência diferente.

## Conclusão

Aprenda os padrões, mas principalmente aprenda suas vantagens e desvantagens, em detalhes. Aprenda quando usá-los e quando evitá-los.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

## Definição

Começando do princípio do que são **"Padrões de Projeto"** (*Design Patterns*)

Os padrões de projetos são soluções genéricas para problemas comuns. Na verdade quando você tenta definir como será resolvido um problema, antes de tê-lo você está se antecipando.

> “Os Design Patterns não exigem nenhum recurso incomum da linguagem, nem truques de programação surpreendentes para impressionar seus amigos e gerentes.” *(GoF, 1995, prefácio vii)*

Isto é, quando utilizar um padrão **MVW** ([*Model-View-Whatever* - Sendo Whatever **o que funcione melhor para você**](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2)) você está resolvendo um problema comum que era a mistura da regra do negócio com a regra da tela e a manutenção fica péssima.

Indo para as aplicações cliente/servidor isso é muito comum de se ver ainda, e continua sendo um problema de manutenção de código.

Não existe uma receita mágica, mas existem vários padrões que podem ser utilizados (Singleton, Builder, Façade, Adapter) e que ajudam a solucionar problemas na construção de aplicações Orientadas a Objetos.

## Portanto

O papel dos padrões de projeto é unificar experiências em soluções de problemas comuns para que outras pessoas possam se beneficiar de uma boa solução encontrada. Simplificando o desenvolvimento e a manutenção, além de facilitar a comunicação como o colega @utLuiz disse, onde desenvolvedores podem dizer:

> Resolvi o problema utilizando um adapter para produzir o mesmo relatório com aquela outra base de dados

Então os outros desenvolvedores saberão qual foi a solução abordada.

Comment: MVC é um padrão de arquitetura de software e ataca um problema recorrente em arquitetura de sistemas, que é separar o modelo da sua representação visual para o usuário. É mais amplo em escopo que um _design pattern_ e envolve componentes _macro_ do sistema. Não é classificado como um design pattern (no sentido dos 23 clássicos catalogados pela _Gang of Four_) porque estes ocorrem num nível mais abaixo, na colaboração entre os objetos (ou módulos, para não se restringir ao paradigma da orientação a objeto). MVC é citado no livro da _GoF_ como uma composição de _design patterns_.