# Por que separar camadas? Quais os benefícios de uma arquitetura multicamada?

Tags: design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Existem **n** tipos de arquiteturas que usam separação de camadas, um exemplo: **Model-view-controller (MVC)**.

- Como criar várias camadas pode ajudar minha aplicação?
- Quais as vantagens de se fazer isso? E as desvantagens?
- Quanto mais camadas "melhor"?
- Quais situações que o uso desse tipo de arquitetura não é recomendado?

*Observação: A pergunta não é sobre MVC, é sobre esse tipo de arquitetura multicamadas.*

Comment: MVC **não** é um tipo de arquitetura, é um *design pattern* que idepende das camadas na sua arquitetura.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Não confundir *multi-layer* com *multi-tier*. Claro que arquiteturas *multi-tier* provavelmente só funcionarão se a aplicação for *multi-layer*.

## Quanto mais camadas "melhor"?

Vou começar pelo mais simples. **Quanto menos camadas, melhor**. É óbvio que a adição de camadas torna o software mais complexo. Claro que isto não quer dizer que apenas uma camada é o ideal. Tem que analisar o problema específico e qual trará mais vantagens.

Certas complexidades existem para resolver certos problemas, para atender certos requisitos. Se não for para isto uma camada é melhor porque ela é mais simples. Hoje quase tudo tem mais camadas porque existem **requisitos** que exigem isto mas ninguém deve tornar o software mais complexo só porque estava escrito em um livro que deve fazer isto.

Há casos que uma camada está bom demais. Não existe motivo para adicionar camadas em sistemas simples com poucas alterações desenvolvido por um programador onde se conhece o exato ambiente onde ele vai funcionar. Tentar adicionar camadas neste caso é ir contra o [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) e adicionar custo de desenvolvimento desnecessário.

Adicionar mais uma camada é útil porque permite separar as regras de negócio da interface com o usuário. Pelo menos isto é o que ocorre na maioria dos casos. Isto é um ganho enorme em termos de organização mas fará você ter que lidar com uma mesma entidade em dois locais diferentes. Tem técnicas para minimizar algumas duplicidades mas complica o desenvolvimento.

Então precisa analisar se o ganho compensa. Só a experiência dá subsídios para isto. E mesmo assim as chances de uma avaliação estar errada é grande. E também não é fácil medir. Por isto é comum as pessoas optarem por um padrão definido e vão com ele em qualquer situação. Parece que é melhor errar porque fez o que todo mundo faz do que fazer o que possivelmente é melhor para o caso específico. Mas não concordo com isto.

## 3 Camadas

O mais comum é ter [3 camadas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_em_tr%C3%AAs_camadas) (dá medo isso só existir em português). Pra falar a verdade não conheço nada útil com mais do que isto. Em 3 camadas as regras de negócio são melhor organizadas separando o modelo dos dados da maneira como elas devem ser manipuladas pela aplicação quando interagem com outras partes, especialmente com a interface de usuário.

O uso de 3 camadas é disparado o mais usado por desacoplar todas as partes necessárias e dar mais flexibilidade na forma de montar a aplicação, sem exageros. Você tem a camada de **apresentação**, de **aplicação** e de **negócios**. Há casos que esta última delega a persistência e outras operações para uma quarta camada. Pode ser exagero. Embora utilizado-se um *framework* que abstraia todo trabalho pode ser vantajoso. Mas aí parece que você só tem 3 camadas novamente.

## Quais as vantagens de se fazer isso? E as desvantagens?

- A maior vantagem é poder trocar certos componentes, tornar as **partes da aplicação independentes**. Poder fazer alterações em uma parte sem afetar as demais.
- Também é útil para que **vários desenvolvedores** (não necessariamente programadores) possam trabalhar na mesma aplicação cada um cuidando da parte em que ele é especialista.
- Fica mais **fácil testar**.

#### Desvantagem

Se o desenvolvimento é feito por uma pessoa ou os desenvolvedores tem suas tarefas definidas por outros critérios e a aplicação não precisa hoje e não vai precisar amanhã de uma mudança de seus componentes, utilizar camadas é masturbação mental. É **aumento de complexidade** à toa.

## Quando usar

Um dos ERPs mais conhecidos do mercado, que eu trabalhei, obteve seu sucesso com apenas uma camada. Claro que em algum momento teve que adicionar camadas, mas ele pode fazer isto quase transparentemente para a aplicação, na maior parte dos casos. E é claro que aprendemos que o marketing é mais importante que a engenharia :)

#### Não usar

Em sistemas internos onde a equipe é bem pequena, o banco de dados é conhecido, se sabe onde vai rodar, quais as exatas necessidades daqueles usuários, camadas costumam ser excesso de zelo. Não crie complexidade onde não precisa.

#### Web

Hoje tem um fator que deve ser considerado. A Web! Sistemas precisam funcionar em uma tecnologia que é *multi-tier* e por isso precisa ser *multi-layer*. E nos casos em que a solução também roda em *desktop* há um motivo a mais para a flexibilidade. Ou seja, o mercado passou ter um requisito que tornou o *multi-layer* **quase** uma obrigação.

#### Escalabilidade

Arquiteturas *multi-tier* costumam permitir mais escalabilidade. E isto passou ser um novo requisito em alguns casos, mas não na maioria. E como dito antes, *multi-tier* exige *multi-layer*.

#### Interface com usuário

Os padrões de arquitetura mais comuns para interface com o usuário (parece ser o foco da pergunta) em 3 camadas são: [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). Provavelmente eles se tornaram conhecidos por estarem atrelados à tecnologias que fizeram sucesso. Ver mais em [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu acho que mais do que 3-tiers é quando quebra-se uma camada em várias. Em Java se vê facilmente, por exemplo, a que eu acredito ser a View pode se subdividir em *Applets* sendo agrupados como *Client Tier* e Servlets sendo classificados como *Presentation Tier*. Claro que um programador Java poderá confirmar melhor do que.

Comment: Pode ser, como não conheço estas tecnologias, não posso afirmar.

Comment: "Quanto menos camadas, melhor." Exatamente isso. Muita gente de Java pega o livro Core JEE Patterns e aplica à risca. Depois ninguém consegue dar manutenção no sistema, já que somente para recuperar uma entidade a partir do Controller o código passa por 500 camadas. O sistemas ficam cheios métodos que só tem uma chamada a outro método e com o tempo várias classes deixam de ser usadas, mas ninguém tem coragem de excluir porque não há rastreabilidade para dar segurança de que elas não são usadas em algum lugar obscuro entre todas as camadas.

Comment: @utluiz Esta é a maior crítica que tenho "ao Java". Os usuários dele aprenderam fazer coisas complexas por *default*. E a educação geral hoje em dia está muito em cima disto. Tem muito material (livros, blogs, etc.) para resolver os problemas realmente complexos mas as pessoas não entendem que os materiais mais antigos que propõem soluções mais simples não estão obsoletos. Eles só não atendem à tudo.

Comment: Deve ter gente que acha que para ser um bom arquiteto, **precisa** criar uma nova camada, hehe. Quadrinho:
http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2013/7/13/foodprints

Answer (score 10):

N Camadas são estilos de arquitetura, MVC é um design pattern. Muitas pessoas confundem isso. Você pode aplicar por exemplo uma arquitetura em 3 camadas junto com o MVC, neste caso ele seria a camada da view.

MVC é bem comum hoje em dia, porém é um termo bem antigo já. Spring MVC, Struts e vários outros utilizam esse pattern.

Dito isso, as arquiteturas em N camadas, separam as responsabilidades de sua aplicação. Por exemplo a de 3 camadas:

1. Interface
2. Lógica
3. Acesso ao banco

A primeira é a interface (HTML, Swing, JSP, JSF, etc etc), onde o usuário irá interagir.

A segunda a parte de negócios (business) onde encontra a maior parte ou toda  a lógica de sua app, como por exemplor, validação, envio de email, cálculos e contas e etc etc.

A terceira e última seria toda a parte do acesso à base.

Viu, se você precisar dar manutenção no acesso aos dados, você irá diretamente a  sua camada relacionada e mudar somente aquela parte do código. Isso é ótimo em grandes projetos

OK... mas pra que tudo isso ?

- Você tem claramente uma separação, que pode ser inclusive de projetos. Oque é excelente quando trabalhado em várias pessoas, pois facilita a manutenção e deploy.
- Desacoplamento: cada camada se comunica uma com a outra através de [Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29).

Quanto mais camadas, não significa, de forma alguma melhor. Por favor leia sobre [Coesão e Acoplamento](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-coesao-e-acoplamento/18538) e também sobre [Granulidade](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2599/granularidade-de-servicos.aspx) que você entenderá melhor o "porque".

**Nota:** Não aplique centenas de design patterns e camadas e etc etc. fique com o simples, quanto mais simples melhor. Programe pensando na manutenção, e nos outros que possam vir a programar em cima de seu código.

Abraços

Answer (score 2):

> Por que usar MVC?

Porque é um verdadeiro padrão de projeto (design pattern) e torna fácil a manutenção da sua aplicação, com pacotes modulares de rápido desenvolvimento. Elaborar tarefas divididas entre models, views e controllers faz com que sua aplicação fique leve e independente. Novas funcionalidades são facilmente adicionadas e pode-se dar nova cara nas características antigas num piscar de olhos. O design modular e separado também permite aos desenvolvedores e designers trabalharem simultaneamente, incluindo a habilidade de se construir um rápido protótipo. A separação também permite que os desenvolvedores alterem uma parte da aplicação sem afetar outras.

http://www.forumweb.com.br/faq/668/cakephp/quais-os-beneficios-de-se-usar-mvc

> Eu sinceramente nunca vi algum tipo de desenvolvimento que não aceite a arquitetura MVC. Considero uma grande evolução na área de programação. Aqui na minha empresa nós já utilizávamos esta arquitetura muito antes dela ser divulgada como hoje é.

Comment: Então o que seria um falso padrão de projeto? Quando você cria camadas, colocar uma nova funcionalidade deve ser feita em vários lugares, isto é mais facilidade? De qualquer forma, a pergunta não é sobre isto.

Comment: Mas só pela organização já é uma arquitetura muito boa bigown e aposto que você intimamente concorda comigo.

Comment: Agora acho que a resposta além de não responder a pergunta, está baseada em opinião. Já é ruim pegar uma resposta integral, mas poderia pelo menos ter pego uma resposta boa.

Comment: Então bigown responda para nós com uma resposta melhor, queremos entender...

Comment: Rogers, eu usei MVC como exemplo, não fiz a pergunta especifica sobre o MVC, vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: Está respondido.

Comment: Realmente bigown, muito boa a resposta não é a toa que sua reputação é alta. Vou ter que votar fazer o que? :P

Comment: cuidado, MVC não é propriamente um design pattern, e sim um architecture pattern.

Answer (score 0):

MVC é simplesmente separar as 3 camadas de Model, View e Controller. É um simples paradigma, uma ideia de que você deve levar em consideração sempre que for desenvolver classes. Sempre procurando não misturar o código de diferentes categorias em uma única classe.

Por exemplo, uma tabela de grid view deve mostrar o conteúdo ao ser carregada, entretanto não deve haver codificação aonde ela busca os dados. Assim como uma função que faz o somatório de uma coluna deve ocorrer no controller.

A separação de responsabilidades permite uma flexibilidade durante a codificação, sendo importante separar a view do model, para posteriormente adicionar outras subclasses.