# Como funciona a comunicação entre as classes a partir das requisições do cliente/usuário no MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, controller

Boa tarde, estou criando meu framework MVC para entender melhor como funciona essa estrutura e o que pode ou não ser feito dentro dela. A estrutura dele está montada assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que eu entendi até agora de MVC acho que é um diagrama normal, mas quem quiser comentar ou dar sugestões fiquem a vontade.

Dentro do `lib_controller` eu criei uma classe principal que faz um filtro inicial das requisições que são feitas antes de chamar um outro controller. Então, no caso dessa url:

> www.site.com.br/home

A classe *principal* chama a classe *home* que se comunica com as classes no `lib_model` e as classes do `lib_view`. Assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classes do Controller:**

Classe Principal

```
class principal {

    function __construct(){

        if(isset($_GET['page'])){

            $class = $_GET['page'];
            require($class.".php");
            $classe = new $class();

        }

    }

}
```

Classe Home

```
class home {

    function __construct(){

        // peça os dados para o model!
        // peça para a view incluir os htmls!

    }

}
```

**index.php**

```
require("lib_controller/principal.php");
$control = new principal();
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

**Isso está errado? É uma má prática você criar nome de classes no controller que são chamados através da url? Isso pode ser um problema?**

Se sim em uma das perguntas... Qual a melhor forma de criar essa comunicação?

Comment: Nome de classes no controller ? O controller contém acções naturalmente, o que perguntas ao certo ?

Comment: @Edilson ... Então... o controler principal é uma classe chamada no index. Ela verifica as requisições inclusive via GET. No caso do exemplo o GET é a HOME então ele chama a classe home que por suas vez conversa com as outras classes no model e na view. Essa é a minha idéia, não sei se está certo isso.

Comment: Olha assim você complica, classe é um conjunto de métodos *(se ainda estiver em falha, pense simplesmente em funções)*, no caso o `index` a que você se refere é *provavelmente* um método da classe e não uma classe.

Comment: Não pode haver classes no controller?

Comment: Você entendeu mal o conceito. Caso consiga arranjar disposição,  e ainda não haja resposta, disponibilizo um exemplo simples para que você entenda mais ou menos como deveria ser.

Comment: Apenas para deixar um ponto claro, algo que as pessoas confundem:
 
1. MVC não é tecnologia propriamente dita é a maneira de como cria/organiza
2. MVC não depende de frameworks e nem orientação a objetos
3. MVC veio antes da Web (junte isto ao item 1)... Resumindo, MVC é apenas uma maneira de organizar e pode ser totalmente opcional, sendo muitas vezes (**muitas mesmo**) usada sem necessidade, ainda mais em páginas web simples, aonde o método de organização poderia ser algo mais simplório e objetivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ainda mais em PHP :) Eu acho incrivel como no Brasil o pessoal adota OOP, MVC e templates em PHP sem a minima noção do que é a linguagem. E o pior: tem cara que tem coragem de ensinar que "isso é o jeito correto" em aula de faculdade, em vez de ensinar o aluno ir direto ao ponto e resolver o problema de maneira objetiva. Ai fica essa bola de neve de gente comprando idéia errada e revendendo, sem saber o que está fazendo. Normalmente programação é questão de raciocínio, mas em PHP é uma "profissão de fé"  :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, eu mesmo já observei algumas respostas úteis suas sobre MVC. Mas no caso, quero entender melhor o conceito na parte de comunicação a partir das requisições dos usuários.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho veja um exemplo bem simplório de como criar algo sem classes e sem MVC, no entanto controlando as tais requisições: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166110/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento legal. Obrigado. É que na verdade estou querendo aprender sobre o MVC. Deixa eu te perguntar... Então o MVC é mais uma forma de organização que separa as responsabilidades de cada parte certo? Não existe uma forma específica de fazer a comunicação entre as partes? Isso é algo que eu posso criar?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu sei que no exemplo que eu dei colocando produtos e home fica meio banal... rsrsrs..

Comment: Como eu disse, MVC não é originário na "webapps da vida", veio bem antes, vc pode criar MVC a maneira que quiser, com OOP ou procedural, desde que mantenha a responsabilidade de cada um em seu devido lugar. O MVC não é tecnologia, vc pode usar um framework como Laravel que "é supostamente MVC" e acabar não trabalhando MVC nele. MVC e afins são interessantes quando necessários, ou se o framework é bem pensado e leve ao mesmo tempo, no geral a maioria não é enxuto e geralmente contem uma série de redundâncias, claro que para desenvolver sistemas grandes são bem vantajosos.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635,
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/3635,
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15916/3635,
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22403/3635 e
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55490/3635 (este ultimo é bem vago, mas a imagem é boa, não é definido que deva ser assim, mas é uma boa maneira de fazer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como já outros disseram ainda nos comentários, o *MVC* não é tecnologia, é apenas uma forma de organizar o projecto, separando em várias partes lógicas que interactuam entre si formando o sistema. No fundo nada muda, afecta apenas a forma como os dados vão transitar de um lado para outro, criando um ponto único de entrada onde todas as requisições ou dados são capturados e logo processados de forma apropriada e logo retornados ao usuário em forma de informação.

**Exemplo usando `POO`:**

```
root
 \-model
   -BaseModel.php
 \-view
   -default.php
   -registar.php
 \-controller
   -DefaultController.php
 index.php
```

*index.php:*

```
<?php

DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $dirs = array('model', 'view', 'controller');
    foreach($dirs as $dir){
        if(file_exists($dir . DS . $class . '.php')){
            require_once $dir . DS . $class . '.php';
        }
    }
});

$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : '';
$m = isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : 'index';
$pedido = isset($_POST) ? $_POST : '';

switch($m){
    case 'qualquerOutro':
        $controller = new QualquerOutro(new QualquerModel);
        break;
    default:
        $controller = new DefaultController(new BaseModel);
}

$controller->load($a, $pedido);
```

*BaseModel.php:*

```
<?php
class BaseModel
{
    private $dados = [
        array(
            'id'=>2,
            'nome'=>'Fulano Jorge'
        ),
        array(
            'id'=>4,
            'nome'=>'Sicrano Antonio'
        )
    ];

    public function get($id=null)
    {
        if(isset($id)){
            foreach($this->dados as $dado){
                if($dado['id'] == $id){
                    return $dado;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->dados;
    }

    public function set($dados)
    {
        foreach($this->dados as $k=>$dado){
            if($dado['id'] == $dados['id']){
                $this->dados[$k] = $dados;
                break;
            } else {
                array_push($this->dados, $dados);
                break;
            }
        }
        # para que se veja a mudança na matriz, já que os dados nao sao mantidos
        var_dump($this->dados);
    }
}
```

*DefaultController.php:*

```
<?php
class DefaultController
{
    private $modelo = null;

    public function __construct($modelo)
    {
        $this->modelo = $modelo;
    }

    public function load($method = 'index', $pedido = array())
    {
        if(!method_exists($this, $method)){
            $method = 'index';
        }
        return $this->$method($pedido);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $html = $this->modelo->get();
        include_once 'view' . DS . 'default.php';
    }

    public function registar($pedido){
        if($pedido):
            $this->modelo->set(['id'=>(int)$pedido['codigo'],'nome'=>$pedido['nome']]);
        endif;
        include_once 'view' . DS . 'registar.php';
    }
}
```

*default.php:*

```
<style type="text/css">
a {color:darkgray; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
ul {margin:1em 0; padding-left:.1em;}
ul li {list-style:none;}
table th {background-color:darkgray;}
table td {padding:.4em;}
</style>
<?php

echo <<<HTML
<h1>Pagina Inicial</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="?a=registar">Cadastrar</a></li>
</ul>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Nome Completo</th>
<th>Acção</th>
</tr>
HTML;
foreach($html as $dado){
    $dd = json_encode($dado);
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" . $dado['nome'] . "</td><td><a href=\"#\" onclick='ver({$dd})'>visualizar</a></td>";
    print "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
<script>
    function ver(obj){
        alert('ID: ' + obj.id + '\nNome: ' + obj.nome);
    }
</script>
```

*registar.php:*

```
<style type="text/css">
a {color:darkgray; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
.field {margin:1em 0;}
</style>
<h1>Cadastrar Novo</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome aqui">
    </div>
    <div class="botao">
        <input type="submit" value="cadastrar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Isto que aí vês, é *MVC*, entrada única, retornos e tratamento separados, e visualização à parte. Na verdade, você consegue fazer isso de várias formas, desde que saiba o que estás a fazer, e o que pretendes alcançar usando isso. O exemplo acima está algo caótico também *(lamentavelmente, ainda assim é o melhor que consegui arranjar em pouco tempo)*, pelo menos para mim, mas deve ser suficiente para passar a ideia.

**Exemplo Procedural:**

```
root
 \-minhas_paginas
   -default.php
   -registar.php
   -404.php
 fnc.php
 index.php
```

*index.php:*

```
<style type="text/css">
a {color:darkgray; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
.field {margin:1em 0;}
ul {margin:1em 0; padding-left:.1em;}
ul li {list-style:none;}
table th {background-color:darkgray;}
table td {padding:.4em;}
</style>
<?php


DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
DEFINE('INC', 'minhas_paginas' . DS);
include_once 'fnc.php';

$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : 'default';

if(in_array($a, ['default','registar','outroQualquer'])){
    if(file_exists(INC . $a . '.php')){
        include_once INC . $a . '.php';
    } else {
        include_once INC . '404.php';
    }
} else {
    include_once INC . '404.php';
}
```

*fnc.php*

```
<?php
$dados = [
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'nome'=>'Fulano Jorge'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>4,
        'nome'=>'Sicrano Antonio'
    )
];

function get($id=null)
{
    global $dados;
    if(isset($id)){
        foreach($dados as $dado){
            if($dado['id'] == $id){
                return $dado;
            }
        }
    }
    return $dados;
}

function set($dados)
{
    global $dados;
    foreach($this->dados as $k=>$dado){
        if($dado['id'] == $dados['id']){
            $this->dados[$k] = $dados;
            break;
        } else {
            array_push($dados, $dados);
            break;
        }
    }
    var_dump($dados);
}
```

*default.php:*

```
<?php
$html = get();

echo <<<HTML
<h1>Pagina Inicial</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="?a=registar">Cadastrar</a></li>
</ul>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Nome Completo</th>
<th>Acção</th>
</tr>
HTML;
foreach($html as $dado){
    $dd = json_encode($dado);
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" . $dado['nome'] . "</td><td><a href=\"\" onclick='ver({$dd})'>visualizar</a></td>";
    print "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
<script>
    function ver(obj){
        alert('ID: ' + obj.id + '\nNome: ' + obj.nome);
    }
</script>
```

*registar.php:*

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    set(['id'=>(int)$_POST['codigo'],'nome'=>$_POST['nome']]);
}
?>
<h1>Cadastrar Novo</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome aqui">
    </div>
    <div class="botao">
        <input type="submit" value="cadastrar">
    </div>
</form>
```

*404.php:*

```
<h1>Pagina nao encontrada</h1>
```

---

Partindo da abordagem *procedural*, fica *"provavelmente"* mais evidente, é algo que se faz muito e às vezes alguns nem notam, quando começam a refactorar o código e por aí adiante.

**M**odel: Modelagem dos dados.

**V**iew: Apresentação da informação *(dados organizados com um propósito...)*.

**C**ontroller: Controla os dados de entrada e o que deve ser apresentado. Basicamente o intermediário, uma vez que a informação na view depende do que é feito no controller.

O processo consiste basicamente, em pegar a informação de algum lugar *(banco de dados por exemplo)*, modelar esses dados, e passa-los ao controlador, e do controlador apresentá-los na view *(Há casos em que pode variar)*. A view deve possuir o mínimo de lógica possível, porque o propósito dela será apresentar a informação ao usuário. O controller por outro lado, é quem deve decidir o que deve ser apresentado na view à partir do model. Uma vez mais, os exemplos não estão como pretendia, mas creio que sejam suficientes para fazer passar a ideia.

> **NOTA:** se ainda existirem erros, ou continuar confuso, corrijo quando tiver tempo.

Comment: Vou olhar direitinho o código com mais calma depois e avaliar. Mas obrigado pelo exemplo.

Comment: Gostei da forma como você montou  a comunicação. Andei me aprofundando mais depois da discussão acima, e vi que os frameworks utilizam rotas (routes) para facilitar essa comunicação do controller as demais partes do MVC. Estou me aprofundando... =) Obrigado.

Comment: Inclusive achei isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135349/como-implementar-um-sistema-de-rotas-no-mvc