# Como funciona realmente o MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Como funciona realmente o MVVM? Quais as responsabilidades da ViewModel e Model?

Estou implementando um projeto com padrão `MVVM` a algum tempo, mas agora surgiu algumas dúvidas sobre o padrão.

Onde implementar a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Aprendi a implementá-lo na `ViewModel`, mas vejo muitos exemplos implementando direto na `Model`.

Outra dúvida seria onde implementar um código do tipo no exemplo, na `viewModel` ou `Model`.
Eu por exemplo definiria o valor de uma `int` e salvaria no `Backend` logo após.

```cs
public class ModelExample
{
  int items {get; set;}
}

public class ViewModelExample
{
  ModelExample modelExemplo {get; set;}

  ViewModelExample(ModelExample modelObject)
  {
    modelExemplo = modelObject;
  }

  //Implemento um metódo desse tipo na ViewModel ou na Model?
  public async Task Adicionar(){
    modelExemplo.Items++;
    //Salva no Backend do Azure (para ilustar o exemplo)
    AzureMobileServices.Instance.SaveDataAsync(modelExemplo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Isso já deve ajudar um pouco: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101

Comment: O padrao diz que a interface só deve ser implementada no ViewModel. Mas porque sou perguicoso costumo meter no model também... Se vai fazer o mesmo ou nao depende da sua experiencia e necessidade.

Comment: A ViewModel representa o comportamento da tela. O INotifyPropertyChanged deve ser implementado em todos os objetos que queiram notificar mudanças de propriedades. Isso é muito comum nas ViewModels e Models. No seu exemplo, o método adicionar deveria ser um ICommand, que é a abstração de ações que serão executadas na ViewModel. Essa ação será atrelada a um botão, por exemplo, via Binding. O mais interessante nisso é que, é possível testar suas ViewModels sem executar o App. É possível aplicar Testes de Unidade nas ViewModels, e pra mim esse é o grande diferencial!

Answer (score 2):

**MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)**

Como nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21539/o-que-%C3%A9-mvp-e-mvvm) já possui a definição e uma explicação básica sobre o MVVM, não vou entrar em muitos detalhes. Vou focar mais na sua dúvida.

Para contextualização, o MVVM é um padrão de projeto baseado em UI, ele é uma aplicação do MVP, que é uma derivação do MVC. Os principais obejetivos do MVVM são: Flexibilidade, Facilidade de manutenção, Modularidade, Testabilidade e Rich UI (interface rica).

**Como funciona realmente o MVVM? Quais as responsabilidades da ViewModel e Model?**

Essa imagem, retirada do [DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-pattern-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm/18411), mostra a arquitetura do MVVM:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A **`View`** é responsável por definir a aparência ou estrutura que o usuário vê na tela. Com a propriedade `DataContext` ela se liga ao `ViewModel`.

A **`ViewModel`** é responsável por disponibilizar para a `View` uma lógica de apresentação. Ela não tem nenhum conhecimento específico sobre a `view`, ou como ela implementada, nem o seu tipo. Ela implementa propriedade e comandos para que a `View` possa preencher seus controles e notificá-la caso haja alguma alteração de estado. Ela implementa a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`

O **`Model`** é o responsável por encapsular a lógica de negócios e dados, sendo o modelo de domínio de uma aplicação. Ele também é responsável pela validação dos dados. Não referencia diretamente a `View` ou `ViewModel`. Uma característica interessante do `model` é que ele provê eventos de notificação de mudança de estado, através das interfaces `INotifyPropertyChanged` e `INotifyCollectionChanged`, facilitando o preenchimento de dados na View.

**Onde implementar a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`?**

Na minha opinião, a `INotifyPropertyChanged` deve ser implementada na `ViewModel`, isso porque essa interface apenas informa uma mudança.

Referências:

- [Introdução ao MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)](http://netcoders.com.br/blog/introducao-ao-mvvm/)
- [Entendendo o Pattern Model View ViewModel MVVM](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-pattern-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm/18411)