# Model/View Programing - WPF e MySQL

Tags: c#, mvc, wpf

Já tinha feito alguns programas em C++ utilizando a framework QT e o seu Model/View Programming(http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html).

O conceito era simples:

- criava um modelo que acedia ao MySQL
- Criava a vista que acedia ao modelo
  ...

Agora que estou a utilizar C# e WPF estou um bocado perdido.
Que ferramentas tenho eu agora ao meu dispor para implementar este tipo de solução?

Um exemplo simples ajudava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O padrão mais comum no `WPF` é o `MVVM` (Model-View-ViewModel) que é uma padrão do tipo `MV*`.

Neste padrão cabem 3 componentes. A vista (que tem um conjunto de controlos organizados de certa forma), o modelo (que tem os dados com lógica) e o ViewModel (que tem a informação a ser apresentada na vista, assim como os eventos dos controlos, tais como cliques de botões).

[image: MVVM]

No MVVM é tipico os controlos suportarem `data-binding`. Isto quer apenas dizer que determinada propriedade do controlo esta ligada a uma propriedade da classe. Por exemplo o texto de uma caixa de texto pode estar ligada a uma propriedade `Nome`. Os bindings também actualizam a vista automáticamente desde que notifiquem a vista. Para notificar a vista é necessário, em `WPF`, implementar a interface`INotififyPropertyChanged` e invocar o evento `PropertyChanged`

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!field.Equals(value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

O método SetField é uma forma simples de invocar o evento. Ele só invoca se o valor mudar.
Agora os seus ViewsModels podem derivar desta classe.

```
public class PessoaViewModel : Model{
    private string _nome;
    public string Nome{
        get{ return _nome; }
        set{ SetField(ref _nome, value); }
    }

}
```

Como expliquei antes os comandos também podem ser `binded`. Os commandos devem implementar a interface `ICommand`. De modo a evitar criar uma classe para cada tipo de comando é comum criar uma que executa qualquer `Action`, passada no construtor da classe:

```
public class DelegatedCommand : ICommand
{
    protected readonly Action<object> _action;
    protected Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    public DelegatedCommand(Action<object> action, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Agora pode adicionar comandos à sua ViewModel. Há várias formas de o fazer, mas vou mostrar aquela que costumo usar:

```
public class PessoaViewModel : Model{
    private ICommand _command;
    public ICommand Command{
        get{ 
            if(_command != null) return _command;
            return _command = new DelegtedCommand((arg) => {
                Console.WriteLine("O código do comando vai aqui");
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Evidentemente os comandos podem mudar o estado das propriedades, se elas invocarem `PropertyChanged` então a interface será atualizada automáticamente.

Por fim uma vista bastante simples (omiti alguns atributos da Window):

```
<Window>   
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:PessoaViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Nome}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Command}" />
    </Stackpanel>
</Window>
```

Referências

[O que é o MVP e MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21539/o-que-%C3%A9-mvp-e-mvvm)

Comment: Nota que no meu exemplo eu não cheguei a implementar nenhum Modelo! Básicamente o meu Modelo é também o ViewModel. Isto não é desejável se o Modelo tiver várias propriedades