# Por que não é recomendavel utilizar o evento em projeto C# com WPF e MVVM?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, engenharia-de-software, mvvm

Eu sou muito novo para o WPF estou fazendo um projeto utilizando MVVM e Entity Framework e foi sugerido não ter nenhum evento `Click` para um botão no código por trás de uma janela, por qual motivo? Qual a alternativa para substituir o evento abaixo sem quebrar as regras sugeridas?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowMenuPrincipal wmp = new WindowMenuPrincipal();
        wmp.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Pode citar referências?

Comment: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/

Comment: o artigo fala sobre `authorization`, onde exatamente fala que não deve ter evento ?

Comment: Este artigo informado anteriormente foi dado como resposta de como utilizar wpf com mvvm sem usar eventos, porém não foi justificado o por que de não se poder utilizar o  evento. Segue o link original para melhor esclarecimento  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72d4eced-f3b8-4898-a7ff-5f8f6e763f0e/wpf-and-mvvm-with-login-authentication?forum=wpf      Onde consta "suggested not to have any Click events"

Comment: `Eu sou muito novo para o WPF` Mas você é sábio além de seus anos, portanto não desista.

Comment: [Fica aqui mais uma pergunta com um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160302/model-view-programing-wpf-e-mysql/160314#160314)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto tem a ver com MVVM e não bem com o WPF. Claro, o WPF costuma usar o MVVM, mas nada impede de fazer através de manipuladores de eventos e abandonar o MVVM. Tem gente que acha que é sacrilégio, mas o mecanismo existe e é válido se souber o que está fazendo. Então entenda melhor como funciona o MMVM (é bem mais complicado que estes *links*, aconselho comprar um bom livro):

- [MVC versus MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214658/101)
- [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101)

O MMVM prega que a apresentação visual deve ser completamente isolada do controle da apresentação, assim a *view* é criada por um designer ou profissional de UX e a forma da "tela" funciona é criada por um programador. Quando você usa manipuladores de eventos em *code behind* acaba misturando as coisas. O MVVM prega o uso do [padrão de projeto Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) para lidar com as ações que a tela dispara ou precisa de atualização.

- [Artigo complementar com mais detalhes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommandWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Pergunta no SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33108122/221800)
- [Tutorial MVVM e Command](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM).
- [Blog sobre o assunto](http://onewindowsdev.com/?p=32).

Sobre o Command:

- [Source Making](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command).
- [OODesign](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html).
- [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern).