# Qual é o propósito dos diretórios gerados automaticamente em um projeto ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

No Visual Studio Community 2015 quando criamos um novo projeto em ASP.NET MVC no projeto é gerado automaticamente a seguinte estrutura de diretórios, veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: Estrutura do projeto MVC]

Sendo no total oito diretórios.

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber qual é o propósito de cada diretório que foi gerado automaticamente?

Comment: Controllers, Models e Views é para uso da estrutura MVC, App_Data acredito que seja para diversos dados usados pelo framework, talvez desde sessão como temporários. A pasta `fonts` foi você quem adicionou?

Comment: A pasta `fonts` também foi criada automaticamente pelo IDE.

Comment: Interessante, deixei um upvote ;) Até mais

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, devo ressaltar que a maioria das pastas são sugestões, e não precisam, necessariamente, serem utilizadas da forma que estão. Dito isso, irei fazer uma breve explicação de cada pasta.

#### App_Data

Essa pasta é indicada para salvar os arquivos físicos, se estiver utilizando. Por exemplo: Irei fazer o upload de uma planilha para meu site e quero salvar em algum lugar. A sugestão da Microsoft é que utilize essa pasta.

#### App_Start

Essa pasta contém as classes que são executadas quando sua aplicação é iniciada. Normalmente vem com os arquivos **BundleConfig.cs**, **FilterConfig.cs** e **RouteConfig.cs** por padrão (se utilizar o modelo *sample* do Visual Studio).

#### Content

Essa pasta é o local indicado para adicionar os arquivos de conteúdos, como **css**, imagens, icones, etc.

#### Controllers

Por padrão, os seus **controllers** devem ser criados nesta pasta. Essa padronização é importante por questões de rotas e ligação com as **Views**. Esse padrão é tão recomendado, que o Visual Studio possui uma função chamada **Go To View**, onde ele abre a **View** referente aquela **Action**.

#### fonts

Local indicado para salvar as fontes utilizadas em sua aplicação. Essas são aquelas fontes para mudar a letra mesmo, aqueles arquivos com as extensões `.eot`, `.svg`, `.woff`, etc.

#### Models

Pasta indicada para salvar os modelos de sua aplicação. Claro, é uma indicação, e se você [utiliza o padrão Repository](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51536/20615) (sei lá por que raios iria fazer isso), você nem precisaria utilizar essa pasta. Porém, não aconselharia fazer isso.

#### Scripts

Acho que essa pasta deve ser a mais óbvia, mas sim. Essa pasta é o local indicado para salvar os **Scripts** de sua aplicação. E sim, os **Scripts** que me refiro são os arquivos `.js`, como o **jQuery.js**, **bootstrap.js**, etc.

#### Views

Por padrão, as suas **Views** devem ser criados nesta pasta. Essa padronização é importante por questões de rotas e ligação com os **Controllers**. Esse padrão é tão recomendado, que o Visual Studio possui uma função chamada **Go To Controller**, onde ele abre o **Controller** referente a esta **View**.

As **Views** são aqueles arquivos com a extensão `.cshtml`, ou seja, o layout de sua aplicação.

Existem mais uma pasta que uma aplicação geralmente possui (criada manualmente), que é a **ViewModel**:

#### ViewModels

Nessa pasta é adicionada as suas **ViewModels**. Caso não saiba do que eu estou falando, [leia essas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/20615) que entenderá melhor.

Como eu disse anteriormente, essas pastas são sugestões da Microsoft. Não é necessário utilizar da forma sugerida. Porém, se você alterar as pastas mais importantes (**App_Start**, **Controllers** e **Views**), você terá sérios problemas se não souber o que está fazendo. Isso porque as rotas (não estou falando do **RouteConfig.cs**) da aplicação estão configuradas para esse padrão, mas se você realizar alterações na pasta, mas não alterar as rotas de forma correta, com certeza sua aplicação irá dar erro.

Answer (score 4):

Esta é a estrutura básica e padrão criada para um novo projeto ASP.NET MVC. Para funcionar, normalmente precisa das pastas `App_Start`, `Views`, `Models` e `Controllers`. Desenvolvedores mais experientes podem optar em criar um projeto totalmente vazio e adicionar as estruturas conforme a necessidade. Porém, por se tratar de MVC provavelmente as pastas Model, Controllers e Views haverá.

A pasta menos comum é a `APP_Data` que é utilizada geralmente para armazenamento de base de dados baseadas em arquivo, como `.dbf` ou .`mdf`. Esta é uma pasta que o IIS irá negar acesso direto por conter dados sensíveis. Por exemplo se colocar arquivos de imagens e tentar entregar para o `client` não irá conseguir acesso de forma trivial.

A pasta `App_Start` é onde por padrão é criado os arquivos de configuração de Rotas, Bundles e Filtros.

A pasta `Content` é onde é criado arquivos de folha de estilo(CSS) e pode ser adicionados imagens também.

`Controllers` é onde é criado os controladores, tanto `ApiController` quanto Controllers comuns.

`Models` é onde é criado os arquivos Models(pode ser ViewModels ou Models), que são representações das entidades de negócio por exemplo, de acordo com a arquitetura. Já vi casos de não houver essa pasta, devido aos models estarem em outra assembly(dll).

Nessa pasta `fonts` são arquivos de fonte(tipografia).

`Scripts` são bibliotecas JavaScript(jquery, jqueryval etc)

`Views` são os arquivos .cshtml.