# Porque usar MVVM em uma aplicação WPF + EF + C#

Tags: entity-framework, wpf, mvvm

Pesquisei em vários fóruns e artigos e todos dizem que devem ser utilizados o padrão MVVM quando for trabalhar com um projeto com EF + WPF.

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque disso? pois quero implementar um sistema mas não sei qual seria o melhor padrão de arquitetura utilizar quando se trata de Entity framework e WPF na linguagem C#

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não é obrigado a seguir padrões, mas é uma boa prática segui-los.

MVVM, nada mais é um padrão com o mesmo proposito do MVC, serve para separar responsabilidades em camadas. Model-View-ViewModel.

**Model:** Camada responsável pelo Modelo de dados ("classes de tabelas")

**View:** Camada de apresentação, layout, formulários, tela

**VieModel:** Camada que faz a comunicação entre Model e View. Onde fica a logica da aplicação, como se fosse a camada de negocio.

Nem tudo deve ser feito na Camada ViewModel, muitas coisas, principalmente, ações que afetam a camada View, como animações, alteração de layout etc.., podem ser feitas na camada View.

A vantagem é a facilidade de manutenção e aplicação em outros projetos. Por exemplo, se desenvolveu para WPF (DeskTop), pode facilmente transferir para Windows Phone ou Windows Aplicativos Modernos, alterando apenas a camada View para cada uma das plataformas, alterando pouco as demais camadas.