# Revisão de código: MVC simples

Tags: java, mvc, javafx, java-8, revisão-de-código

#### Hello world!

Tentei fazer um MVC bem simples em JavaFX. Meu modelo é uma classe `Pessoa` que possui `nome` e `idade` (o campo `idade` no caso não chega a ser usado). Dois *text fields* representam duas visões. Por simplicidade ambas mostram a mesma coisa: o nome da pessoa. Se você editar um dos nomes e der *Enter*, a mudança se reflete no modelo e por tabela nos dois *text fields* novamente.

#### Perguntas:

1. Este código está em MVC?
2. Quem é o controlador?
3. Não deveria haver uma classe para o modelo chamada "Modelo"?
4. Não deveria haver uma classe para o controlador chamada "Controlador"?
5. O método `start()` não deveria ser o mais simples possível, consistindo somente em ligar as partes envolvidas (Modelo, Visões e Controlador)?
6. Quais outras críticas podem ser feitas a essa tentativa de MVC?

#### App.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private final Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Mario", 39);

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        atribuirTituloAoPalco("Hello World!", stage);

        TextField visao1 = criarTextField(pessoa.getNome(), e -> pessoa.setNome(((TextField)e.getSource()).getText()));
        TextField visao2 = criarTextField(pessoa.getNome(), e -> pessoa.setNome(((TextField)e.getSource()).getText()));

        pessoa.adicionarObservadorDoNome(nome -> visao1.setText(nome));
        pessoa.adicionarObservadorDoNome(nome -> visao2.setText(nome));

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        root.getChildren().add(visao1);
        root.getChildren().add(visao2);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(v -> pessoa.removerObservadores());
        stage.show();
    }

    private void atribuirTituloAoPalco(String titulo, Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle(titulo);
    }

    private TextField criarTextField(String texto, EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setText(texto);
        textField.setOnAction(eventHandler);
        return textField;
    }
}
```

#### Pessoa.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
  * É responsabilidade do implementador da classe escolher tipos imutáveis para os campos que serão observados
  * por cada observador (exemplo: String para nome, Integer para idade) caso contrário o observável irá "vazar"
  * estado para o observador.
  */
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;

    private int idade;

    private final Set<Observador<String>> observadoresDoNome = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<Observador<Integer>> observadoresDaIdade = new HashSet<>();

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        notificarQueNomeMudou();
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
        notificarQueIdadeMudou();
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void adicionarObservadorDoNome(Observador<String> observador) {
        observadoresDoNome.add(observador);
    }

    public void adicionarObservadorDaIdade(Observador<Integer> observador) {
        observadoresDaIdade.add(observador);
    }

    public void notificarQueNomeMudou() {
        for (Observador<String> observador: observadoresDoNome) {
            observador.notificar(nome);
        }
    }

    public void notificarQueIdadeMudou() {
        for (Observador<Integer> observador: observadoresDaIdade) {
            observador.notificar(idade);
        }
    }

    public void removerObservadores() {
        observadoresDoNome.clear();
        observadoresDaIdade.clear();
    }
}
```

#### Observador.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Observador<T> {
    void notificar(T observavel);
}
```

### EDIT:

Analisando a resposta e comparando a um exemplo de MVC com FXML achei [um outro exemplo sem FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873768/2241463) que veio a calhar. Baseei-me nele, porém sem usar objetos `*Property` do JavaFX, e tenho agora o seguinte código:

#### App.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Mario", 39);

        Controlador controlador1 = new Controlador(pessoa);
        Visao visao1 = new Visao(pessoa, controlador1);

        Controlador controlador2 = new Controlador(pessoa);
        Visao visao2 = new Visao(pessoa, controlador2);

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        root.getChildren().add(visao1.comoComponente());
        root.getChildren().add(visao2.comoComponente());

        atribuirTituloAoPalco("Hello World!", stage);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(v -> pessoa.removerObservadores());
        stage.show();
    }

    private void atribuirTituloAoPalco(String titulo, Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle(titulo);
    }
}
```

#### Controlador.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop;

public class Controlador {

    private final Pessoa pessoa;

    public Controlador(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    public void atualizar(String nome) {
        pessoa.setNome(nome);
    }
}
```

#### Visao.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;

public class Visao {

    private FlowPane visao;
    private TextField campoNome;

    private Pessoa pessoa;
    private Controlador controlador;

    public Visao(Pessoa pessoa, Controlador controlador) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
        this.controlador = controlador;

        criarEConfigurarPane();
        criarEDisporControles();
        atualizarControladorAPartirDeListeners();
        observarModeloEAtualizarControles();
    }

    private void criarEConfigurarPane() {
        visao = new FlowPane();
    }

    private void criarEDisporControles() {
        campoNome = new TextField();
        campoNome.setText(pessoa.getNome());
        visao.getChildren().add(campoNome);
    }

    private void atualizarControladorAPartirDeListeners() {
        campoNome.setOnAction(v -> controlador.atualizar(campoNome.getText()));
    }

    private void observarModeloEAtualizarControles() {
        pessoa.adicionarObservadorDoNome(nome -> campoNome.setText(nome));
    }

    public FlowPane comoComponente() {
        return visao;
    }
}
```

Ficou melhor? Agora Visão e Controlador são classes e o método `start()` foi simplificado para apenas ligá-los entre si e ao Modelo.

Por esse código concluo que vai custar um pouco pro padrão entrar na cabeça porque eu começo pelo Modelo que é desconexo dos demais, em seguida vou para a classe Visão que é o início do fluxo, passo pelo Controlador e retomo a codificação da Visão. Fica meio não-linear o desenvolvimento se seguir por essa linha.

Notei também que a classe `Controlador` ficou completamente dispensável, está certo isso?

Em tempo, o modelo deve ser observável via de regra?

Comment: Olhando assim, não é MVC. O modelo parece claro, mas o controlador e a visão estão misturados.

Comment: Tá mais pra um MVP do que MVC, na minha visão. Neste caso, a classe `App` faria o papel do _presenter_ e a _view_ parece estar "escondida" porque você não faz uso de um código separado para apresentar os dados. Mesmo pra MVP não tá bem de acordo porque a view e o presenter ficam misturados.

Comment: Vixe. Não peguei o conceito então. Acho que essa pergunta vai render uma boa resposta :)

Comment: Eu diria para ser feliz usando MVWYW, mas no caso você realmente deseja MVC nas coisas

Comment: A propósito, é Java 8? Se sim, dá para deixar mais elegante usando uns lambdas...

Comment: Creio eu que MVC não se limita a códigos, mas sim a estratégia, pra notar as diferenças de interpretações ou estratégias que as pessoas adotam veja um exemplo da Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html (é razoalvemente semelhante a abordagem adotada pelo Qt, claro que dá pra vc fazer como desejar)....

Comment: ...Assim, em uma humilde opinião não adianta muito criar um MVC proprio e ainda sim ele se tornar algo burocrático de organizar, quero dizer, seria mais interessante criar um controlador (main) que selecionaria "sozinho" o controller para o view desejado, algo que seria semi-automatico e organizado em algum tipo de estrutura com os namespaces talvez, ou seja o seu App.java esta "manual" e parece ser o unico "controlador" (teoricamente), acho que da forma que esta não compensa querer usar esse design, acho que poderia procurar "automatizar" as coisas e organiza-las.

Comment: Sim, é Java 8. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado "MV Whatever You Want"? Não sei se você quis dizer para eu usar alternativas a MVC ou fazer o que me der na telha :P Tenho dificuldades com os conceitos (mesmo as perguntas do site nem sempre me ajudam) e acredito que devo praticar o básico, e como sei que JavaFX dá certo com MVC, bora praticar MVC :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código apresentado parece mais um modelo [MVP (*Model, View, Presenter*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/18246) do que MVC. Sendo sucinto, a principal diferença entre os dois padrões é que no MVC existe um controlador que decide qual visão será "mostrada" em resposta a alguma ação e no MVP existe um *presenter* que serve para conter a lógica da visão e a própria visão "se comunica" com o modelo.

De forma geral (não vou entrar em detalhes porque tem várias perguntas sobre isto no site) o MVC pode ser resumido por esta imagem:

[image]
<sup>**Imagem retirada de: www.devmedia.com.br/guia/asp-net-mvc/38190**</sup>

Como dito anteriormente, os modelos devem ser as entidades do domínio da aplicação, os controladores são responsáveis por receber as "ações" da visão e entregar uma nova visão. A visão é quem decide como os dados serão mostrados para usuário (por exemplo: um código HTML pode definir uma visão).

---

Tentando focar nas suas perguntas:

> Quem é o controlador?

Exatamente, ele não existe aí. Até pode-se dizer que a classe `App` é o controlador porque ela chama a *view* ao final (estou supondo que `stage.show()` faça isto).

> Não deveria haver uma classe para o modelo chamada "Modelo"?

Não. O modelo está correto, a classe `Pessoa` é um modelo, assim como **todas as classes referentes ao domínio da aplicação** serão o modelo. Por exemplo, se for aprimorar a aplicação e decidir que também é possível cadastrar carros, a classe `Carro` será também um modelo e assim por diante.

> Não deveria haver uma classe para o controlador chamada "Controlador"?

Sim. Quer dizer, o nome da classe quem escolhe é você, isso vai ser indiferente, mas deveria assim existir uma classe para fazer o papel de controlador.

> O método `start()` não deveria ser o mais simples possível, consistindo somente em ligar as partes envolvidas (Modelo, Visões e Controlador)?

Eu, sinceramente, não faço ideia de qual o papel do método `start()` no contexto do padrão MVC. Ele me parece mais um método de ponto de entrada da aplicação do que algo relacionado ao padrão.

> Quais outras críticas podem ser feitas a essa tentativa de MVC?

Além do que foi citado, me parece que você tentou tratar cada `textField` como uma visão diferente. Esta abordagem não está correta, a visão é a tela. Por exemplo: um conjunto de `textField`'s e outros componentes formam uma visão. Ou seja, uma visão é uma **tela** ou parte de uma.

Comment: Vide minha edição da pergunta.