# Bloquear Botão Formulario - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin-forms

Gostaria de saber como posso bloquear um botão de fazer uma ação, no Xamarin.Forms, caso determinadas variáveis não estejam preenchidas. Segue o codigo que tenho na minha ViewModel:
//Esse é o construtor da minha ViewModel

```
public MinhaViewModel()
    {            
        //os campos dessa variável precisam estar preenchidos
        this.cidadeDestino = new CidadeDestino();

        //Botão para enviar a busca que precisa estar bloqueado.
        this.BuscaPartidasCommand = new Command(() =>
        {

          MessagingCenter.Send(cidadeDestino, "BuscaCidade");

        });       
    }
```

A variável cidade destino é do tipo de uma classe que eu criei, ela possui dois parâmetros do tipo string, apenas isso, e esses dois parâmetros devem ser diferentes de "null" para que o botão possa executar sua ação. Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No padrão [**`MVVM`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21580/78713) no `Xamarin.Forms` geralmente isso é tratado com o recurso do `Command` chamado `CanExecute`.

Com ele, ao associar um comando a um botão, toda vez que houver alteração no `CanExecute` do comando e a resposta for `False`, o botão ao qual o comando está associado também fica desabilitado.

Desenvolvendo sobre o cenário que você tem, teríamos algo como o que eu vou mostrar a seguir.

#### O seu modelo seria algo assim:

```
public class CidadeDestino : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string nome;
    public string Nome
    {
        get { return nome; }
        set
        {
            if (value != nome)
            {
                nome = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Nome");
            }
        }
    }

    private string siglaEstado;
    public string SiglaEstado
    {
        get { return siglaEstado; }
        set
        {
            if (value != siglaEstado)
            {
                siglaEstado = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SiglaEstado");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Considerando esse cenário, em resumo, sua condição do `CanExecute` é "Nome da cidade e sigla do estado devem ser diferentes de nulo".

Então, continuando o desenvolvimento...

#### Na tela (XAML)

```
...
<Entry Text="{Binding NomeCidadeDestino}"
       Placeholder="Nome da Cidade"
       .../>
<Entry Text="{Binding SiglaEstadoCidadeDestino}"
       Placeholder="UF"
       .../>
<Button Text="Confirmar"
        Command="{Binding ComandoConfirmar}"
        .../>
...
```

<sub>* - Apesar de ter difinido a tela no XAML, se a definição for feita via C# o efeito é o mesmo.</sub>

E construindo a outra camada...

#### Na View Model

```
public class MinhaViewModel
{
    private CidadeDestino cidadeDestino = new CidadeDestino();
    public Command ComandoConfirmar { get; }

    public string NomeCidadeDestino
    {
        get { return this.cidadeDestino?.Nome; }
        set
        {
            cidadeDestino.Nome = value;
            ComandoConfirmar.ChangeCanExecute(); // Aqui você 'informa' que o estado do comando deve ser reavaliado
        }
    }

    public string SiglaEstadoCidadeDestino
    {
        get { return this.cidadeDestino?.SiglaEstado; }
        set
        {
            cidadeDestino.SiglaEstado = value;
            ComandoConfirmar.ChangeCanExecute();
        }
    }

    public MinhaViewModel()
    {
        ComandoConfirmar = new Command(ExecutarConfirmar, () => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cidadeDestino?.Nome) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cidadeDestino?.SiglaEstado));
    }

    private void ExecutarConfirmar()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(cidadeDestino, "BuscaCidade");
    }
}
```

E o resultado dessa implementação seria:

[image: Exemplo da implementação funcionando]

Agora é só pegar essa ideia e aplicar no teu cenário real que deve resolver. Esse mesmo `CanExecute` costuma tambem usar uma propriedade comum nas ViewModels, que geralmente alterna a visibilidade daquelas márcaras de "carregando". A mesma ideia se aplica.

Avise me se ainda restar alguma dúvida.

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Olá Diego, sua resposta me ajudou demais, precisei fazer pequenas alterações por causa do meu código mesmo, mas a ideia foi a mesma. Muito obrigado.