# Diferenças nos construtores usando propriedade vs campo (field)

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, construtor, propriedade

```
namespace WMB.CieloB
{
     internal class FuncoesCielo
     {
           internal FuncoesCielo(int iDC, Boleto boleto) 
           {
                IDCliente = iDC;
                this.boleto = boleto;
            }

            public int IDCliente { get; set; } 

            internal Transaction PagamentoComToken()
            {
                 var holder = cielo.holder(IDCliente);
                 Order orderDadosDoboleto = cielo.order(boleto.BoletoId.ToString(), boleto.Valor );
            }
      }
}
```

Estou chamando essa classe através do:

```
namespace WMB.CieloB
{
    public class Cobrancas
    {

        public bool ExecutarRecorrenciaCompleto()
        {
            IDC = 3;
            var boleto = db.boleto.Find(1);//apenas exemplo
            var NewPagamento = new FuncoesCielo(IDC, boleto);
            var transacao = NewPagamento.PagamentoComToken();
}
}}
```

> Ou seja tanto a propriedade IDCliente quanto boleto estarão disponível
>   dentro da classe, porém uma é propriedade (IDCliente), outro é um field
>   (Boleto), normalmente declaro um field igual a uma variável nesse caso nem declarei.

**Qual diferença de utilizar o `IDCliente` como método do que o `this.boleto` que nem foi declarado (`Boleto boleto;`) mas posso acessá-lo dentro da classe.**

Comment: Bom, não tem a propriedade ou campo `boleto`, acho que foi só um deslize, certo? `MyVar` também surgiu do nada. Não sei bem o que está perguntando. Quer saber porque tem que criar uma propriedade? Quer saber se poderia usar um campo público e não ter a propriedade? Quer saber a diferença entre colocar o valor no campo pelo construtor ou pela propriedade?

Comment: não foi um deslize, mesmo não criando ainda posso acessa-lo! Apenas da diferença entre uma propriedade e um field que nem é declarado.

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de por a classe toda para dar mais contexto. Pelo menos coloca como o campo `boleto` está declarado.

Comment: Acho que agora ficou mais clara a pergunta, se eu colocar minha classe especifica creio que só vai servir pra mim, modifiquei a pergunta para que possa ajudar mais alguém.

Comment: Isto está esquisito. Eu acho que sem o contexto, não dá para ver o que está errado. É muito estranho não ter um campo `boleto` e estranho funcionando. Em situações estranhas, sem contexto fica difícil saber o que está acontecendo. Eu quero tentar reproduzir o problema aqui, mas só com isso não consigo.

Comment: Eu respondi o que deu, mas depois das edições estou pensando em votar em fechar como não clara. Cada vez vez faz menos sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro é bom entender bem [para que serve um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Aí já começa clarear porque é diferente fazer a inicialização nele ou na propriedade. A não ser que esteja usando C# 6 ou superior e a [inicialize diretamente com um valor padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101). O mesmo pode ser feito com o campo, em todas versões sempre pode inicializar com valor padrão. Fora isto, é possível inicializar as propriedades/campos públicos na inicialização de objeto. Tem efeito semelhante ao de fazer no construtor.

Se o dado não for inicializado durante a construção do objeto, por construtor ou não, o seu valor inicial será um padrão do tipo criado. Será um 0, um nulo, etc. E depois poderá ser alterado se a propriedade/campo permitir isto. [Pergunta que ajuda entender isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54334/101).

O fato de existir uma propriedade significa que ela pode ser acessada externamente. Se vai poder mudar seu valor ou não, depende de como ela é declarada. Lembrando que é comum uma propriedade ter um campo para guardar o valor, o estado, mesmo que ele não apareça no código, este campo costuma ser privado.

É possível usar um campo público para obter o mesmo efeito, mas isso costuma ferir a abstração/encapsulamento e não há controle granular sobre o acesso. Tanto leitura quanto escrita ficam públicos. [Outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101) pode ajudar entender a propriedade um pouco mais.

Obviamente que se tiver um campo privado somente a própria classe poderá acessá-la. Um campo privado pode ser acessado no construtor ou qualquer método dela, mas nada de fora.

Quanto ao campo `boleto` acessível eu diria que é impossível, principalmente por ser `this.boleto`,  mas não vi o contexto completo.

O AP não quis colocar um contexto maior, então agora vou começar especular sobre
o fato do campo `boleto` estar sendo acessível mesmo sem ter sido declarado na classe.

Se a classe herda de uma outra e na outra tem um campo com visibilidade `protected`, então está acessando o campo da propriedade base.

Se há um campo em outra classe no mesmo *assembly* com visibilidade `internal` também daria acesso para as demais classe.

Do jeito que está [o código nem compila](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WLJgwf).

Depois das edições o código ficou mais esquisito ainda.

Comment: vou colocar completo..e compila sim..rs

Comment: realmente tinha um campo field, como a classe era grande não vi que o visual studio colocou lá embaixo private Boleto boleto;

Comment: Então, é algo que tem no seu projeto. É difícil responder sem ver o contexto todo. Agora estou pensando em votar pra fechar como não reproduzível (ainda não votei em nada claro, estou te dando a chance de definir melhor o problema). Se puder fornecer mais alguma informação que ajude identificar como está.

Comment: Sei lá, manda *screenshot* do VS, mostre o que mais tem nesse projeto. Eu realmente queria entender porque está compilando aí.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? O que era?

Comment: Sim, falha minha total, Como a classe era grande não vi que o visual studio colocou lá embaixo private Boleto boleto; achei que só com o this.Boleto seria acessivel, achei q era alguma ultra super novidade do C# 6..rs