# Propriedade Vs variáveis

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, propriedade

Sempre usei propriedades no C# desta forma:

```
public int Numero { get; set; }
```

Hoje eu me perguntei, por que eu uso esse `get` e `set` ao invés de uma variável?

Existe diferença? Apenas uso assim porque aprendi assim, mas não sei o motivo.

```
public int numero;
```

Existe diferença entra usar as propriedades conforme a primeira e segunda forma?

Primeira forma:

```
public int Numero { get; set; }
```

Segunda forma:

```
private int numero;
public int Numero
{
    get
    {
        return numero;
    }
    set
    {
        numero = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ótimo ter perguntando. Nunca é legal sair usando coisas sem questionar. Mesmo que acerte será por coincidência.

Os dois códigos de uso da propriedade (os do fim da pergunta) são equivalentes. Podemos dizer que o segundo será o código realmente gerado quando usa o primeiro. Não existe nenhuma razão para escrever o segundo (neste caso).

A forma do segundo só é útil quando foge deste padrão tão comum, que é apenas ter um campo privado de suporte e a lógica de atribuição e acesso a este campo por métodos *acessadores* (sim, [na verdade são criados internamente dois métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108529/101) para acessar o campo privado, e eles só são otimizados no acesso interno da classe).

Mesmo que precise que a escrita no campo seja privada, é possível marcar o `set` como `private` na primeira forma.

No passado um motivo para fazer tudo separado era quando queria inicializar um valor na propriedade quando o objeto fosse criado. O único jeito era fazer isso no campo, então precisava destrinchar tudo. O C# 6 passou permitir a [inicialização na própria propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101).

```
public int Numero { get; set; } = 5;
```

No C# 6 se a propriedade tiver apenas um `get` com lógica e não tiver um `set` pode fazer de forma mais simples:

```
public int Numero => numero;
```

Normalmente deveria ter uma lógica mais complexa que esta, mas neste caso específico é o mesmo que:

```
public int Numero { get; };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/PropXVar.cs).

Essa forma é chamada de *expression body* e é muito parecida com uma [*lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101), embora não seja uma.

Em C# 9 é possível usar um `init` no lugar do `set` e permitir que a propriedade seja inicializada, depois não pode mais ser alterada.

## Propriedade é realmente necessária?

Na verdade é pra se pensar se realmente precisa dar acesso à propriedade. Costuma-se dizer que os campos internos devem ser acessados através de outros métodos mais significativos e não através de *acessadores* diretos. Claro que isso é exagero na maior parte dos casos. Tem situações que a única coisa que se deseja é acessar a propriedade pura e simplesmente. Aí faz sentido.

Só pense antes se realmente está fazendo o que é necessário. Se for, a propriedade não tem problema algum, só não faça no automático.

Vejo casos que nunca terá um acesso público à propriedade, então não tem porque criá-la. Tem casos piores, o acesso público direto a ela pode causar algum problema para aquela classe.

Tem *frameworks* que exigem que o acesso seja feito pelas propriedades. É o caso do Entity Framework. Faz sentido ter essa exigência - mais abaixo explico porque. Aí tem que criar.

## Por que não dar acesso ao campo público?

Também pode-se questionar se deve criar uma propriedade ou simplesmente dar acesso público ao campo. Pensa bem, pra que criar uma propriedade que faz o mesmo que o acesso ao campo diretamente já oferece?

Em geral as pessoas não sabem como responder isso. Fazem porque leram em algum lugar que é assim que deve ser. Mas ninguém deveria fazer algo só por causa disso, deve ter um motivo.

Em outras linguagens que não possuem essa sintaxe de propriedade é muito comum exigir a criação dos métodos *getter* e *setter* porque vai que seu código inicialmente ofereça o campo público, aí mais pra frente uma manutenção exija que o acesso faça um pequeno processamento. Vamos dizer que na atribuição de um valor para o campo precise fazer uma validação. Ou para pegar o valor precisa fazer um rápido cálculo antes. O que fazer? Muda o campo para privado, cria os dois métodos de `get` e `set` e manda todo mundo que consumiu sua classe mudar os códigos deles para acessar o campo pelos métodos à partir de agora. Se sua classe é popular, pode ser que milhares de programadores do mundo todo tenham que fazer isso. Inviável, certo?

O C# não sofre desse problema, porque sintaticamente o acesso pelos métodos *acessadores* é idêntico ao acesso pelo campo direto.

Problema resolvido então? Não. O problema dos consumidores de sua classe permanece.

Quando o consumidor compila e tem acesso ao campo, é um acesso à uma variável, uma posição de memória. Igual em outras linguagens. Quando muda para uma propriedade, os métodos são automaticamente criados e ficam disponíveis para uso. Os códigos **fontes** consumidores da classe não precisam ser mexidos. Mas eles já foram compilados do outro jeito (acesso à memória diretamente). Isso não muda sozinho.

Você resolve o problema se compilar de novo o código consumidor da sua classe. Na nova compilação será visto que agora é uma propriedade e gerará o acesso pelos métodos auxiliares criados pelo compilador na classe que foi mudada. Fácil de resolver.

Mas nem sempre você pode garantir que uma mudança na sua classe gerará uma nova compilação nos códigos consumidores para atender a nova [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) (sim, a API muda). Se sua classe é distribuída para terceiros ou ela é usada pelo EF, por exemplo, você não pode controlar isso, mesmo que queira.

Então sempre que você pode garantir que essa compilação será feita, ou seja, em projetos internos que você tem controle, ou se a execução tem algum controle de versionamento que não vai chamar a versão "errada" da biblioteca, você pode usar o campo direto. E isso tem vantagens de performance (se precisa desta vantagem ou não, é outra coisa).

Mas se não tem controle sobre o consumo, o melhor é já garantir que o código consumidor faça acesso pela propriedade, assim os métodos já são chamados em vez do acesso ser feito pela variável. Então quando você mexer na sua classe todos os códigos consumidores chamarão o método com o código novo, já que a criação uma função/método é uma forma de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). E...

> [Todos os problemas da computação podem ser resolvidos com um nível extra de indireção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

Feito isso o código consumidor não precisa mais se preocupar em como o acesso à propriedade é feito, ele chama o método e o que estiver lá dentro será executado. Se você mexeu na sua classe, vai refletir nessa execução, porque o *binding* (vinculação) da implementação da função é sempre dinâmica (em tempo de execução). Já a decisão do que chamar é sempre feito em tempo de compilação (pelo menos em linguagens estáticas), por isso causa o problema de versões diferentes. Só pode garantir que elas sejam compatíveis se forem compiladas em sincronia.

#### Princípio *Open/Close*

Tem o princípio *Open/Close* que faz parte do [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Algumas pessoas pregam que isso deve ser seguido estritamente em OOP. Se isso for seguido mesmo então não existe nenhuma razão para usar propriedades ou métodos *getter*/*setter*. Daí conclui-se que ou esse princípio é tolo ou essa ideia de encapsular as coisas não fazem sentido.

Eu prefiro ficar com o que eu sempre digo, faça o que tem que fazer em cada caso. Se quer criar um contrato, respeite o contrato e não o mude, se sabe que a implementação pode mudar e não pode controlar seus efeitos, prepare o código para lidar bem com isso.

O uso da propriedade faz sentido quando ela será virtual, uma variável nunca pode ser virtual.

Agora sabe porque usar a propriedade e quando ela não é necessária.

Relacionado:

- [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)
- [Diferenças nos construtores usando propriedade vs campo (field)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124742/101)

Comment: Obrigado @bigown.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi mais ou menos, quer dizer então que se eu estiver trabalhando em uma classe que eu tenha certeza absoluta que as variáveis(campos) nunca precisarão de um processamento ou uma validação antes de ser setada ou obtida eu posso criar apenas a variável sem nenhum problema mas se eu não tenho essa certeza e que talvez futuramente outras pessoas irão consumir essa classe e variável e eu precise fazer um processamento ou uma validação direto nela é melhor eu já criar como propriedade para não ter esse problema futuro, é isso?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Basicamente é isto. Na verdade mesmo que você tiver certeza que os consumidores sempre serão compilados de novo se você mudar a sua classe também pode usar a variável direta sem passar pela propriedade. Mas tem que ter todas essas certezas, se tiver qualquer chance disso não ser garantido, é melhor ir pro caminho seguro e criar a propriedade. Tem gente que prefere seguir a regra cegamente e fazer sempre. Até funciona, mas é bom saber que tem como fazer de outro jeito.