# Por que declarar propriedades duas vezes em uma classe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade

Ao declarar uma propriedade em uma classe, costumam declarar duas vezes, uma pública e a outra privada. Qual o objetivo?

```
private int _years;
public int Years
{
    get { return _years; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não está declarando a propriedade duas vezes, está declarando um campo e uma propriedade que usa este campo. Em algo simples assim não é necessário fazer desta forma, pode fazer:

```
public int Years { get; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Simple.cs).

O campo é automaticamente declarado internamente (não fica disponível para seu código, nem dá para saber o nome que usado salvo com reflexão, o que não faz sentido fazer).

Quando precisa fazer algum algoritmo dentro da propriedade aí precisa declarar o campo explicitamente já que a propriedade deixa de ser automática.

Se o campo, e não a propriedade, for necessário em outros pontos da classe, então precisa declarar fora. Mas isto raramente é necessário.

Nem sempre precisamos de propriedades. Tem até uma escola que é contra elas já que ela não tem uma função definida. Eu acho academicismo.

Tem casos que um [campo público pode ser útil ou até melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101), quando se sabe o que está fazendo.

Answer (score 9):

O primeiro propósito da existência de propriedades no C# é permitir que a classe exponha publicamente valores(estado) mantendo privado(encapsulado) a sua implementação e validação.

Isso é conseguido recorrendo ao uso de um campo privado(*backing field*) cujo valor é acedido através dos métodos `get()` e `set()` da propriedade.

A declaração do *backing field* pode ser feita implicitamente(automaticamente) ou explicitamente.

A declaração explicita do *backing field* é necessária se quiser/precisar tirar proveito do propósito de usar propriedades.

Answer (score 5):

Atualmente o C# admite que você declare uma propriedade assim:

```
public Foo foo { get; set; }
```

E por baixo dos panos você tem o campo privado para guardar um valor através do nome da propriedade e ser lido com o nome da propriedade.

Isso nem sempre foi assim... Nas versões antigas, você precisava declarar o campo.

Hoje você só precisa de um campo privado dessa forma se a propriedade for somente para escrita ou somente para leitura.

Em tempo, o membro `_years` na sua pergunta é um campo, não uma propriedade. Existe uma diferença entre as duas coisas, que eu deixo a seu critério pesquisar (ler documentação é chato mas é didático).