# Existe diferença entre usar Funções GetCoisa e SetCoisa e usar metodos gets e sets em variáveis?

Tags: c#, unity-5, getters-setters

Olá boa noite eu estava no meu curso programando um jogo em C# na unity.
E como sei pouco de c#, acabo tendo algumas dificuldades e tudo mais.

Eu estava criando várias funções gets e sets tanto para obter as respostas, quando para mudar o que tivesse que se mudado, mas fiquei na dúvida quando fui ver um vídeo no YouTube sobre get e sets e gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de usar.

**Código de exemplificação do que estava fazendo no curso**

```
int qualquerCoisa;

public int getQualquerCoisa(){
 return qualquerCoisa;
}
public void setQualquerCoisa(int coisa){
 qualquerCoisa = coisa;
}
```

**E o código que estava vendo no YouTube era parecido com o debaixo**

```
private int coisa;

public int Coisa{
   get{
     return coisa;
   }
   set{
     coisa = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263498/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205396/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405783/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306914/101

Comment: obrigado pelos os links, irei ler com mais calma