# Essa relação entre classes estaria correta?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, modelagem, uml

Atualmente estou estudando sobre classes, mais especificamente relacionamento de classes/UML e estou fazendo isso em C#. Eu gostaria de saber se esse código que escrevi abaixo é o mais adequado ou se existe uma forma diferente e mais eficiente de fazê-lo.

Se trata de um programa bem simples que relaciona as classes: Banco, Conta Corrente, Conta Poupança e Cliente (peço desculpas pelo tamanho do código no exemplo);

```
using static System.Console;

public class Cliente
{
    private string nome;
    private float saldo;

    public Cliente(string nome)
    {
        this.nome=nome;
        saldo=0;
    }

    public string GetNome()
    {
        return nome;
    }

    public float GetSaldo()
    {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void SetSaldo(float atualizar_saldo)
    {
        saldo+=atualizar_saldo;
    }
}

public class ContaCorrente
{
    private Cliente cliente;

    public void AbrirConta()
    {
        cliente = new Cliente("João");

        cliente.SetSaldo(50.0f);
    }

    public void FecharConta()
    {
        cliente = null;
    }

    public void Sacar(float valor)
    {
        cliente.SetSaldo(valor);
    }

    public void Depositar(float valor)
    {
        cliente.SetSaldo(valor);
    }

    public Cliente GetCliente()
    {
        return cliente;
    }
}

public class ContaPoupança()
{
    private Cliente cliente;

    public void AbrirConta()
    {
        cliente = new Cliente("Maria");

        cliente.SetSaldo(100.0f);
    }

    public void FecharConta()
    {
        cliente = null;
    }

    public void Sacar(float valor)
    {
        cliente.SetSaldo(valor);
    }

    public void Depositar(float valor)
    {
        cliente.SetSaldo(valor);
    }

    public Cliente GetCliente()
    {
        return cliente;
    }
}

public class Banco
{
    private ContaCorrente conta_corrente;
    private ContaPoupança conta_poupança;

    public void IniciarContaCorrente()
    {
        conta_corrente = new ContaCorrente();

        conta_corrente.AbrirConta();
    }

    public void IniciarContaPoupança()
    {
        conta_poupança = new ContaPoupança();

        conta_poupança.AbrirConta();
    }

    public void InformaçõesDaConta()
    {
        WriteLine($"Nome do Cliente Conta Corrente: {conta_corrente.GetCliente().GetNome()}");
        WriteLine($"Saldo em sua Conta: {conta_corrente.GetCliente().GetSaldo()}");

        WriteLine($"Nome do Cliente Conta Poupança: {conta_poupança.GetCliente().GetNome()}");
        WriteLine($"Saldo em sua Conta: {conta_poupança.GetCliente().GetSaldo()}");
    }
}

public class MainProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Banco banco = new Banco();
        
        banco.IniciarContaCorrente();
        banco.IniciarContaPoupança();

        banco.InformaçõesDaConta();

    }
}
```

O meu objetivo nesse código era testar se ele funcionaria como eu esperava que funcionasse, também compreender melhor como funcionam as relações entre as classes e como elas devem ser feitas.

Comment: O Cliente vai ser sempre "João" para `ContaCorrente` e sempre "Maria" para `ContaPoupanca` ? O  Saldo não deveria ser das contas ao invés do `Cliente`? Um cliente não pode ter uma conta corrente e uma poupança? Porque você não incluiu o diagrama das classes na pergunta?

Comment: A parte do nome do cliente foi intencional, apenas para efeito de exemplo. A parte do saldo eu realmente fiz a leitura errada, deveria mesmo ser propriedade das contas corrente e poupança. É que esse é o meu primeiro contato com relacionamento de classes, ainda estou aprendendo sobre o diagrama :)

Obrigado pelo comentário

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programação envolve entender completamente o problema e as técnicas usadas. Sem informações precisas sobre o problema não dá para ter certeza se está certo ou errado. Decorar fórmulas para fazer, certamente está errado.

UML, provavelmente, está fazendo aprender algumas coisas do jeito errado (por exemplo vai aprender [falar atributo onde tem um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) na linguagem real), porque é uma forma muito conceitual, digo isso olhando para o código. Ao mesmo tempo não há uma conceituação correta pelo exposto no parágrafo anterior, ou seja, sem informação precisa temos que declarar algo errado fundamentalmente.

Orientação a objeto é mais sobre entender o problema e criar objetos que façam sentido para esse problema do que decorar mecanismos de linguagens, principalmente linguagens abstratas como UML. E novamente, para criar objetos corretos precisa ter entendimento completo do problema real, concreto, não um problema artificial.

OO depende de dar nomes adequados para as coisas, classificar corretamente.

[`float` não é o tipo correto para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[C# tem propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) e deveria usá-las, e de forma adequada, [quase todo mundo usa *getters/setters* no automático e erra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) (o *link* é só para começar estudar o assunto). Não deveria permitir atualizar um saldo diretamente, só para dar um exemplo. `GetCLiente()` parece o jeito burocrático de fazer isso.

Eu queria falar de [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), mas a classe atualmente é tão sem sentido que não adiantaria, mas parece que usará do jeito errado.

Não faz sentido abrir uma conta com nome e valor fixo, pode ser só para começar, mas fazer pelo menos o contrato da classe certo é importante para saber se ela e as suas relações estão certas.

Parece fazer menos sentido anular o valor de um campo. A questão é saber se deveria aceitar ser nulo. Em versão moderna da linguagem o certo é não aceitar até que o domínio exija isso. Deveria buscar outra solução.

As classes tendem a precisar de alguns outros métodos auxiliares que não fazem parte do domínio, mas nem vou entrar nisso porque o básico precisa ser arrumado.

Parece que precisaria de uma classe abstrata chamada `Conta` para servir de base para as outras duas contas concretas. Mas é aquilo que eu falei, só com mais informações concretas para saber se é para fazer isso mesmo.

Não consigo imaginar como um cliente pode ter saldo. Quem tem isso é a conta.

`Banco` parece uma classe completamente incoerente, não parece que deveria ter esse nome ou mesmo se deveria existir tudo nela. Pode existir uma classe para modelar um banco mas seria algo muito diferente disso.

Se for fazer algo realista falta muita coisa, um banco é mais complexo que isso. Se for fazer algo artificial que só você sabe, então tudo o que estiver na sua cabeça está certo, e tem pouco ou zero valor para aprendizado real.

Se quiser saber sobre a conta do cliente pode ser mais difícil com esse modelo, mas não posso afirmar que está erado.

Tem muitos erros básicos para avançar com isso. Parece que está querendo aprender como decorar uma casa quando ainda não aprendeu assentar um tijolo. Eu mudaria a forma que está aprendendo.