# Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

No Java tenho por costume por criar atributos privados e criar os métodos *getters* e *setters*, por conta do encapsulamento. Não consegui entender direito como isto funciona no `C#`.

Comment: O que exatamente você não entendeu, poderia posta uma parte com exemplo disso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Em C# o que você chama de atributo é tratado como campo, já que [atributo é outra coisa na linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101) (algo [semelhante a anotação do Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101)). Na verdade [depois de estudo vi que em quase todas as linguagens o nome correto não é atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Embora possa fazer exatamente igual no C#, não é idiomático. C# possui um açúcar sintático que facilita o seu uso. No fundo o que está sendo feito internamente é criar um campo e um par (até pode ser só um) de métodos (`get` e `set`). O que muda é na chamada.

Em vez de chamar um

```
x + objeto.getValor()
objeto.setValor(10)
```

usa-se

```
x + objeto.Valor
objeto.Valor = 10
```

A declaração disso seria algo assim:

```
public int Valor { get; set; }
```

Que é o mesmo que escrever:

```
private int valor;
public int {
    get { return valor; }
    set { valor = value; }
}
```

Note que `value` é uma palavra-chave contextual, ela é o parâmetro que recebe o valor a ser *setado*. Essa sintaxe mais longa só é usada quando precisa criar uma lógica específica diferente da padrão.

O mesmo código em Java seria algo assim:

```
private int valor;
public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}
public void setValor(int value) {
     valor = value;
}
```

Obviamente que assim como o Java, é possível colocar qualquer lógica ali dentro. Se entender que no fundo aquilo é um método, fica fácil compreender o seu uso.

É possível indicar que o `set` seja privado e pode [colocar um valor inicial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101) (C# 6 para cima). Este exemplo cria uma propriedade que não pode ser mudada externamente:

```
public int Valor { get; private set; } = 10;
```

Ou pode ser toda [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101):

```
public int Valor { get; } = 10;
```

Idealmente nesse caso a inicialização deveria ser em um construtor de forma parametrizada. Da maneira feita aí uma propriedade estática e somente leitura seria melhor, já que o valor não é parametrizável e nunca muda. Mas isso é assunto para a [construção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Em C# 9 tem a possibilidade de apenas inicializar a propriedade e `get`, mas não mudar o valor depois da inicialização:

```
public int Valor { get; init; };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Explanation.cs).

As [propriedades podem ser inicializadas na construção até mesmo onde não existe um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101). Mas pode haver [diferenças semânticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124742/101) nisso.

Já respondi sobre o assunto em diversas perguntas:

- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) (nem sempre a propriedade é necessária)
- [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)

Comment: @bigown então quando eu declaro, por exemplo:

public int Numero { get; set; }

Esta propriedade é privada e os métodos get e set públicos? O que define uma propriedade pública então?

Comment: @elvex O campo é privado, e os métodos (que não parecem métodos) são públicos, portanto essa é uma propriedade pública. Essa é uma propriedade pública, o que alias faz pouco ou nenhum sentido criar uma propriedade privada, ainda que possa fazer. Talvez tenha um problema de terminologia aí. Se está falando de campo público pode fazer também se quiser, igual ao Java. Sugiro ler os *links* colocados para pegar mais detalhes.

Comment: @bigown vou dar uma lida nos links assim que possível. Mas o que eu quis dizer foi: no Java eu costumo criar atributos(propriedades do C#) com o modificador private e os métodos get/set com public. Ou seja, métodos públicos e atributo privado. No C# já é declaro o atributo com public. Pelo que entendi, isto faz com que os métodos sejam públicos. O que eu queria entender é: a propriedade também fica pública? O acesso a ela é direto? Ou é sempre pelo get/set?

Comment: @elvex Propriedades no C# são somente um açúcar sintático para o uso de get/set de uma maneira mais elegante, permitindo usar uma sintaxe mais amigável. E as propriedades possuem por padrão uma auto-implementação, caso você não especifique como o get/set deve funcionar, ele mesmo cria um campo privado e trabalha de maneira simples com ele. Você pode ver aqui (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102639/are-c-sharp-properties-actually-methods) como uma propriedade auto-implementada acaba virando um código C# equivalente com uso de métodos e campos.

Comment: Vale lembrar que, desde o C# 6, é possível utilizar lambdas pra definir propriedades read-only (`public int SegundosAgora => {DateTime.Now.Seconds}`)

Answer (score 5):

O C# simplifica parte disso pra você, embora, em baixo dos panos, seja exatamente a mesma coisa.

Você definir um modificador de acesso para o atributo (no C#, chamamos de propriedade) no geral

```
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

**Nome** terá seu *getter* e *setter* públicos.

Você pode também, definir separadamente

```
public string Nome { get; private set; }
```

Neste caso, **Nome** terá o *setter* privado e *getter* público.

Comment: Ok, já mudei e vou excluir os comentários que não acredito ser válido agora.