# Como alterar propriedade de outro objeto?

Tags: unity3d

Tenho uma tela com dois objetos 2d: `player` e `enemy`, ambos são `prefab` de um objeto chamado `fighter`.

Eles tem três propriedades: `attack`, `defense` e `hp`.

Criei um script e incluí na câmera, ele é quem vai controlar o jogo.

Quero saber como fazer o script da câmera diminuir o `hp` de um dos meus objetos.

Classe `fighter`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class fighter: MonoBehaviour {

    public int attack;
    public int defense;
    public int hp;
    public int mp;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        int range = Random.Range (150, 200);
        attack = range;
        range = Random.Range (100, 150);
        defense = range;
        range = Random.Range (800, 1000);
        hp = range;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Classe que está na câmera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class turnBased : MonoBehaviour {

    private BattleStates currentState;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    void Update() {
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        if (GUILayout.Button ("ATTACK")) {
        //crio um botão e ao ser clicado, deve causar dano ao inimigo
        enemy.hp -= 10; //<<<<aqui deve vir o código
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Colega, sua pergunta não está nada clara (mas não fui eu quem negativou, ok?). Primeiramente, qual é o nome da classe que esses objetos usam? É `fighter` mesmo? Se sim, você tentou fazer `player.GetComponent<fighter>().hp = 2;`, por exemplo? Coloque trechos do seu código, senão ninguém conseguirá te ajudar.

Comment: @LuizVieira alterado. espero que consiga ajudar melhor agora. abraço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa ter uma referência local para os objetos que quer manipular. Há diversas formas de obter essa referência:

1. Você pode criar dois objetos públicos do tipo `fighter` e atribuir, via editor da Unity (selecione e arraste os objetos do jogador ou do inimigo para o atributo da classe `turnBased` no inspetor, enquanto a câmera estiver selecionada).
2. Você pode procurar pelos objetos internamente, usando tags ou o tipo do objeto (se fossem diferentes) ou pelo nome.

Se você tem dois objetos que são fixos, o método 1 é o melhor. De fato, ele é o mais utilizado e aconselhado nos treinamentos da Unity. Mas vou exemplificar com o método 2, usando o nome dos objetos para encontrá-los.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class turnBased : MonoBehaviour {

    private BattleStates currentState;

    public fighter player;

    public fighter enemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("player");
        if(obj != null) {
            player = obj.GetComponent<fighter>();
            if(player == null) {
                Debug.LogError("Objeto 'player' não tem o componente 'fighter'");
            }
        }
        else {
            Debug.LogError("Não encontrei objeto com o nome 'player'");
        }


        obj = GameObject.Find("enemy");
        if(obj != null) {
            enemy = obj.GetComponent<fighter>();
            if(enemy == null) {
                Debug.LogError("Objeto 'enemy' não tem o componente 'fighter'");
            }
        }
        else {
            Debug.LogError("Não encontrei objeto com o nome 'enemy'");
        }
    }

    void Update() {
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        if (GUILayout.Button ("ATTACK")) {
        //crio um botão e ao ser clicado, deve causar dano ao inimigo
        enemy.hp -= 10; //<<<<aqui deve vir o código
        }
    }
}
```

> Além disso, fica aqui outras dicas:
>
> - Não adicione o script de controle do jogo na câmera. Crie um objeto vazio (`empty`), talvez chamado de "gameController", por exemplo, e
>     adicione esse script lá. A câmera somente deveria ter código relacionado a coisas de câmera (translações, rotações, zooms, seguir personagem, etc).
> - Não mude o HP do inimigo (ou do jogador) diretamente da classe de controle. Invoque um método do tipo "Tomar Dano" (algo como
>     `takeDamage`) passando o total de dano. Ou faça o atributo público
>     `hp` se tornar uma [propriedade realmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156804/como-funcionam-as-propriedades-no-c) (com *getter* e *setter*). Assim
>     você tem mais controle sobre o que acontece quando dano é recebido
>     diretamente na classe interessada, e pode fazer outras coisas (tocar
>     animações, por exemplo).

Comment: Luiz, deu certo sim, mas fiquei com uma dúvida: como atribuir os objetos `fighter` em tempo de execução? Digamos que eu tenha 5 deles. Quando o jogador clicar em um, ele é atribuído automaticamente.

Comment: Não sei o que vc quer dizer com "atribuir". Mas se a ideia é adicionar o **componente** (script) `fighter` a um objeto, basta usar `objeto.AddComponent<fighter>();`. Veja a documentação do [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html). Vc precisa entender bem a distinção de componente e objeto na Unity, ou se explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Como foi respondido, existem vários caminhos, mas seria bom evitar sempre que possível usar os meios que envolvem busca (FindObjectOfType, FindGameObjectsWithTag, SendMessage, etc) por uma questão de performance.

Você pode declarar uma variável "public GameObject alvo" dentro da classe Fighter e lá na cena arrastar o player para a variável "alvo" de enemy via inspetor e vice-versa.

Caso os "alvos" fiquem mudando/variando, você pode criar um método no inimigo recém instanciado que informa ao player que ele é seu novo alvo.