# As validações feitas no set, não estão funcionando. C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Estou treinando POO, e num exercicio com herança, fiz os Gets e Sets, e nos sets eu fiz algumas validações nos atributos, porem quando instanciei o objeto e passei os parametros, nao mostrava mensagem de erro, nesse caso por exemplo, "Se o id for <=0 dar um erro, ai passei como parametro um numero negativo, porem ele imprime o valor normal e nao da nenhuma mensagem de erro.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Item
    {
        private int id;
        private string descricao;
        private string genero;
        private string autor;
        private int dataLancamento;


        public Item(int id, string descricao, string genero, string autor, int dataLancamento)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.descricao = descricao;
            this.genero = genero;
            this.autor = autor;
            this.dataLancamento = dataLancamento;
        }

        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }

            set
            {
                if (id <= 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("O ID informado é inválido");
                }
                id = value;
            }
        }

        public string Descricao
        {
            get { return descricao; }

            set
            {
                if (descricao == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("A Descrição informada é inválida");
                }
                descricao = value;
            }
        }

        public string Genero
        {
            get { return genero; }
            set
            {
                if (genero == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("O genêro informado é inválido");
                }
                genero = value;
            }
        }

        public string Autor
        {
            get { return autor; }
            set
            {
                if (autor == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Autor informado é inválido");
                }
                autor = value;
            }
        }

        public int DataLancamento
        {
            get { return dataLancamento; }
            set
            {
                if (dataLancamento <= 0 )
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(" O Dia informado é inválido");
                }
                dataLancamento = value;
            }
        }

        public class CD : Item
        {
            private string idioma;

            public CD(int id, string descricao, string genero, string autor, int dataLancamento, string idioma) : base(id, descricao, genero, autor, dataLancamento)
            {
                this.idioma = idioma;
            }

            public string Idioma
            {
                get { return idioma; }
                set
                {
                    if (idioma == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("O Idioma informado é inválido");
                    }
                    idioma = value;
                }

            }

            public void mensagem()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: " + ID);
                Console.WriteLine("Descrição: " + Descricao);
                Console.WriteLine("Genero: " + Genero);
                Console.WriteLine("Autor: " + Autor);
                Console.WriteLine("Idioma CD: " + idioma);

            }

        }

    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CD cd = new CD(-1587, "Teste", "", "Teste", 1002, "Portugês");

            cd.mensagem();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/137387)

Comment: Você tá validando pelo backing field sendo que ele ainda não foi atualizado... Se trocar as validações pra usar o `value` vai funcionar.

Comment: opa, perdão, não consegui entender

Answer (score -1):

Cara acredito que você esteja fazendo de forma errônea da prop ID, pois Você está validando o valor id ao invés do valor value

dentro do seu set tenta fazer:

```
if (value <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("O ID informado é inválido");
}
id = value;
```

Não sei se ajudaria, mas tenta ai :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).