# Erro de objeto não instanciado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Eu tenho uma *model* chamada `ClientesModel`. Dentro dela tenho os campos:

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int codcli { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string nr { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
```

Tenho também uma *model* chamada estados com os seguintes campos:

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sigla { get; set; }
```

Como faria para *linkar* essas duas *models*? Tentei fazer assim:

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int codcli { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string nr { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public EstadosModel estado { get; set; }
```

E ao colocar as informações na *model*, usar dessa forma:

```
    ClientesModel c = new ClientesModel();
    c.id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id"]);
    c.codcli = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["codcli"]);
    c.nome = Convert.ToString(Dr["nome"]);
    c.endereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["endereco"]);
    c.nr = Convert.ToString(Dr["nr"]);
    c.bairro = Convert.ToString(Dr["bairro"]);
    c.cidade = Convert.ToString(Dr["cidade"]);
    c.estado.id = 1;
    c.estado.sigla = Convert.ToString(Dr["sigla"]);
```

Mas acaba apresentando erro.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Sei que preciso instanciar o objeto mas não sem onde nem como instanciar um objeto.

Não sei se também se estou fazendo confusão e deveria usar os 2 *models* separados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se atendo especificamente ao seu problema, o objeto `c.estado` precisa ser instanciado antes de você atribuir algum valor às propriedades `id` e `sigla`.

Você pode realizar isto no próprio método:

```
ClientesModel c = new ClientesModel();
c.id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id"]);
c.codcli = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["codcli"]);
c.nome = Convert.ToString(Dr["nome"]);
c.endereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["endereco"]);
c.nr = Convert.ToString(Dr["nr"]);
c.bairro = Convert.ToString(Dr["bairro"]);
c.cidade = Convert.ToString(Dr["cidade"]);
//Instanciando um novo estado e atribuindo sua referência a c.estado
c.estado = new EstadosModel();
c.estado.id = 1;
c.estado.sigla = Convert.ToString(Dr["sigla"]);
```

Assim como também pode colocar um construtor default na classe ClientesModel:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public int codcli { get; set; }
public string nome { get; set; }
public string endereco { get; set; }
public string nr { get; set; }
public string bairro { get; set; }
public string cidade { get; set; }
public EstadosModel estado { get; set; } 
//Construtor padrão
public ClientesModel()
{
     this.estado = new EstadosModel();
}
```

### Notas

- As propriedades em c# seguem a nomenclatura PascalCase (i.e primeira
  letra de cada palavra maiúscula, por exemplo: CodigoCliente)
- Dê preferência a um código mais legível do que a um código mais 'enxuto'. Não há necessidades (a primeira vista, pelo menos) por exemplo de abreviar a propriedade `codcli`, ou a propriedade `numero`.
- Sempre que for criar uma nova variável, tente fazer com que seu nome seja o mais explicativo possível. Em códigos complexos ou extensos, esta característica pode ser um diferencial muito grande para o correto entendimento do código sem um grande esforço.
- Quando for nomear suas classes, utilize o plural apenas quando ele fizer sentido. Se sua classe representa apenas um cliente, não faz sentido colocar seu nome no plural (clientes). O mesmo para estado e estados. Um bom exemplo para se utilizar o plural está em propriedades que são listas, que representam mais de um objeto.

Seguindo as recomendações acima, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

**ClienteModel.cs**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CodigoCliente { get; set; }
public string Nome { get; set; }
public string Endereco { get; set; }
public string Numero { get; set; }
public string Bairro { get; set; }
public string Cidade { get; set; }
public EstadoModel Estado { get; set; }
```

**EstadoModel.cs**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Sigla{ get; set; }
```

**Main.cs**

```
ClienteModel cliente = new ClienteModel();
cliente .id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id"]);
cliente.codcli = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["codcli"]);
cliente.nome = Convert.ToString(Dr["nome"]);
cliente.endereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["endereco"]);
c.nr = Convert.ToString(Dr["nr"]);
cliente.bairro = Convert.ToString(Dr["bairro"]);
cliente.cidade = Convert.ToString(Dr["cidade"]);
cliente.estado.id = 1;
cliente.estado.sigla = Convert.ToString(Dr["sigla"]);
```

Comment: Nossa Muito Obrigado pelas dicas.. Estou começando agora a desenvolver em Camadas e apesar de estar fazendo faculdade de Analise, ainda não cheguei nessa materia e estou sem a quem perguntar algumas dúvidas básicas..

Com relação ao Construtor padrao

          public ClientesModel()
         {
                 this.EstadosModel = new EstadosModel();
         }

não seria:

        public ClientesModel()
        {
             this.estado = new EstadosModel();
        }

Comment: Exatamente. Corrigido ^^

Comment: Ai sim..!! Vc é Kra..!! Muito Obrigado pela Ajuda..!!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Vinicius está perfeita, pelo menos na medida que dá em cima do código apresentado (não vou entrar em detalhes do que poderia ser diferente que não é o foco da pergunta). Vou só mostrar uma outra forma de fazer a inicialização do objeto se estiver usando C# 6 para cima:

```
public EstadosModel Estado { get; set; } = new EstadosModel();
```

Assim não precisa ter o construtor, pelo menos não para isto.

Outra melhoria possível é usar [inicialização e objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54334/101):

```
var cliente = new ClienteModel {
    id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id"]),
    codcli = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["codcli"]),
    nome = Dr["nome"],
    endereco = Dr["endereco"],
    nr = Dr["nr"],
    bairro =Dr["bairro"],
    cidade = Dr["cidade"],
    estado.id = 1,
    estado.sigla = Dr["sigla"]
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ObjectInitializer.cs).

Como eu imagino que o dado vem como *string* nesse dicionário, não tem porque converter para *string*.

Note que se existir alguma razão para o dado vir mal formado, o `Convert.ToInt32()` vai gerar uma exceção, isto não é o ideal.

Tem certeza que o código do cliente precisa ser numérico?

E aproveitando para fazer notas de estilo, siga o [guia de estilo do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).

Comment: Bigown.. Obrigado pela dicas... Aproveitado a oportunidade... Como vc melhoraria o código? Eu estou pensando em separar o endereço e tbm tenho uma tabela separada de telefone com nome e telefone... Como vocês modelariam essa classe..?

Comment: Aí já fica muito extenso pra dizer aqui, já é outro problema. E precisaria de um contexto maior da aplicação. Vou te dar um exemplo: ter uma tabela apenas com uma sigla de estado me parece exagerado. Sai mais barato e é mais simples colocar a sigla direto.

Comment: Entendi... Eh que a ideia eh ter as cidades, Estados e os ceps colocados na base.. Com eh uma aplicação a princípio desktop, talvez não tenha perda de desempenho

Comment: Aí começa ter algo completamente diferente, ainda assim isto não parece fazer sentido. Mesmo que faça, faz pouco sentido preparar uma parte dos dados para o futuro e uma parte deixar simplificadamente. Curiosamente faz até mais sentido (não que faça por completo) a cidade e outros dados serem separados em uma classe, e isto não foi feito.