# Sintaxe de inicialização de propriedade estranha pra mim

Tags: c#, entity-framework, classes, construtor, propriedade

Ao ler um tutorial sobre Entity Framework, me deparei com um exemplo de código onde existia uma linha que, para mim, é desconhecido:

```
Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };
```

Eu entendo que está sendo instanciado um novo objeto do tipo `Student`, mas as instruções entre chaves são estranhas para mim. O que é isso? Por acaso uma segunda forma que C# dispõe para inicializar uma propriedade do objeto?

Nesse caso eu sou familiarizado com a forma trivial, ou seja, através do construtor.

```
Student stud = new Student(StudentName = "New Student");
```

Comment: A sintaxe para construtores com argumentos nomeados é `var stud = new Student(studentName: "New Student");`.

Comment: Matheus, lhe aconselho a dar uma lida nas novidades do c# 6.0. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Inicializador de objeto

Isso é um [*object initializer*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). É uma forma de iniciar os membros de um objeto independente de ter um construtor.

Ele funciona de forma análoga ao construtor, mas pode inicializar qualquer membro público (não pode acessar membros privados, a não ser ser por forma indireta com um método público, exatamente como ocorre com o construtor).

Tem basicamente as mesmas características de um construtor, mas a ordem de inicialização não é garantida (depende de como o programador usar na criação do objeto) ao contrário do construtor que determina a exata ordem de inicialização, e pode ainda executar operações auxiliares durante a inicialização.

Entenda [para que serve um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Veja um [exemplo prático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54334/101).

Na verdade a sintaxe poderia ser até mais simples:

```
var stud = new Student { StudentName = "New Student" };
```

Isso é o mesmo que fazer:

```
var stud = new Student();
stud.StudentName = "New Student";
```

Mas com a vantagem que o objeto só estará disponível para a aplicação ao final da execução das duas linhas. Escrito de forma separada um programador pode pôr alguma coisa no meio dessas linhas em futuras versões e parar de fazer o que se se esperava.

Note que `StudentName` é uma propriedade pública da classe (ou um campo público, o que é raro que seja).

Nada garante que todos os membros necessários serão inicializados adequadamente usando essa forma. O construtor é melhor quando isso é importante.

Conforme pode observar na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) a mesma sintaxe é possível com a inicialização de coleções.

## Construtor com argumentos nomeados

Já a segunda sintaxe é um construtor como outro qualquer, mas está usando um [argumento nomeado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Por coincidência o parâmetro tem o mesmo nome da propriedade, mas não se engane, ali é o nome do parâmetro, e não da propriedade. O mais adequado de acordo com o [estilo normalmente adotado em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101)  (e consertando o erro de sintaxe observado pelo Thiago Lunardi em comentário - veja mais abaixo que pode ser que a sintaxe possa estar correta) seria:

```
var stud = new Student(studentName : "New Student");
```

Essa sintaxe pode ajudar dar melhor semântica à construção do objeto. Aparentemente neste caso não há maior vantagem. Este uso é mais vantajoso quando o método tem vários parâmetros e melhor ainda quando alguns possuem valores padrão. Assim é possível usar os argumentos na ordem que quiser e fica mais fácil omitir os que já possuem valores.

Essa sintaxe é totalmente dependente da [assinatura do construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

[Diferença entre parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Note que a sintaxe pode estar certa. É ruim, é confuso, mas poderia estar fazendo uma [atribuição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) de `"New Student"` para uma variável chamada `StudentName`  e usando o valor dessa variável como argumento do construtor.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/b278YL). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GOj5Yo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ObjectInitialization2.cs).

Muito disto pode ser evitado com os campos, ou até mesmo as [propriedades já inicializadas na classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101).

Importante observar que C# 9 apresentou novidades no assunto e construtores serão um pouco menos usados em certos cenários.

Comment: A sintaxe para construtores com argumentos nomeados é `var stud = new Student(studentName: "New Student");`.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi é verdade, copiei o dele e nem me atentei a este erro, obrigado. Se quiser corrigir... Se não, eu faço jájá.

Comment: Não consigo corrigir, pois exige alterar no mínimo 6 caracteres, e aí é apenas 2. :)