# Porque esta divisão na instanciação de classes em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, instanciar-objeto

No livro "[Use a Cabeça - C#](https://g.co/kgs/VH4Mg0)", o autor declara classes de uma forma que não compreendi sua utilidade, segundo o exemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    Farmer farmer;

    public Form1 () {
        InitializeComponent();
        farmer = new Farmer() { NumberOfCows = 15};
    }
}
```

Não compreendi a diferença desta forma declarativa e da divisão dela em duas sentenças, as duas diferentes localizações, de simplesmente declarar:

```
Farmer farmer = new Farmer(){ NumberOfCows = 15};
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o tour como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa entender [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Leia lá e praticamente terá sua resposta.

Agora, se quer saber porque não foi feito fora do construtor, assim:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Farmer farmer = new Farmer { NumberOfCows = 15 };
    public Form1() => InitializeComponent();
}
```

É algo que só o autor do código pode explicar. Pelo menos nesse caso. Talvez a intenção dele tenha sido mostrar que você pode declarar a variável na classe e pode inicializá-la com um valor no construtor.

Se for isso, pode ser que, hipoteticamente, queria dar a ordem certa da inicialização de cada coisa. Como já foi dito na outra pergunta, o construtor é a única forma que você pode controlar a ordem de inicialização. Na forma como foi escrito a variável `farmer` começa com um valor nulo e só depois que passa pelo construtor é que gera um valor. Pode ser que seria uma exigência da classe `Farmer` fazer desta forma, mas nada indica.

Pode ser que foi feito assim porque mais pra frente ensinará inicializar direto no campo `farmer` na classe sem passar no construtor.

Também pode ser que a pessoa que escreveu esse código não sabe que sempre pôde inicializar direto no campo ou até mesmo na propriedade desde C# 6. Tem um monte de livro que é escrito por quem não domina a tecnologia. Essa linha de livros é escrita pensando na cognição do leitor, eu não sei se a parte mais técnica tem o mesmo esmero que eles dão para a pedagogia.

Eu já não gosto, por exemplo, do fato de ensinarem criar um formulário chamado `Form1` quando talvez deveria ser um `FarmerForm`. O livro parece incentivar vícios de programação.

Note que eu tirei até os parênteses ali na inicialização do objeto. Eu falo com mais detalhes sobre o assunto em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101). Se sua dúvida é essa, lê lá para entender como isso funciona.

Pra falar a verdade dei uma lida nesse capítulo do livro e achei confuso.

Entenda que se a construção do objeto em `farmer` depender de algum parâmetro que viesse de `Form()` então faria sentido inicializar no construtor, afinal é o único jeito de parametrizar sua construção. Mas a classe `Form` não é para ter métodos construtores com parâmetros. Até pode, mas ela não foi criada pensando nisso. Pode ser que não construa do jeito que imagina se criar um construtor com parâmetros. Então na minha opinião foi feito assim apenas por gosto.

Agora, se sua dúvida é porque não faz assim:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Farmer farmer = new Farmer { NumberOfCows = 15 };
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/MemberOrLocal.cs).

Isto estaria errado nesse contexto. Desta forma `farmer` é uma variável local, portanto ela deixaria de existir no fim da execução do método. Isto tem a ver com [escopo e tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) (leia lá para entender melhor).

Nesse caso, em tese, a variável deveria ser usada por todos os métodos do objeto criado por `Form1`. Mais uma vez não gosto muito do exemplo. Porque se é para explicar o conceito de criação de um campo acho que deveria usar uma classe mais simples e não envolver `Form` nisso. Se a intenção é ensinar usar a classe `Form`, e não parece ser o caso, deveria fazer de um jeito que ele tivesse utilidade.

Comment: ótima resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Na linha:

```
Farmer farmer = new Farmer(){ NumberOfCows = 15};
```

significa que o atributo `NumberOfCows` esta sendo inicializado, veja você pode fazer desta maneira, exemplo:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa 
{
  Nome = "Gato",
  Idade = 25
}
```

É uma forma simples de inicializar as propriedades sem ter que passar diretamente no construtor

```
new Pessoa("Gato", 25)
```

e você pode inicializar a propriedade que quiser.

Já a divisão

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Farmer farmer;
}
```

Usa o comando `partial` que é uma forma de dividir a classe, geralmente é usado por geradores de código.

Answer (score 2):

`Farmer farmer;` **não instancia** nada. Isso apenas declara uma variável do tipo **`Farmer`**.

A instância desta variável é feita no segundo exemplo (**`farmer = new Farmer() { NumberOfCows = 15 };`**).

Obviamente eu não posso dizer o porquê do autor fazer isso. Pode ser estilo de codificação, ou pode realmente ter um motivo plausível pra isso.

Um bom exemplo seria que esta variável será usada em todo os escopo do `form` (como se fosse global para o `form`), mas precisa ser instanciada apenas na chamada do construtor (que é exatamente o que acontece no exemplo) porque alguma definição vem "de fora", ou seja, é feita alguma validação com dados vindos do "*caller*" do formulário.

---

Dando um exemplo bem simplório com base no código da pergunta, seria o seguinte:

Imagine que por algum motivo qualquer, exista a propriedade **`NumberOfTractors`** que **só pode ser definida dentro da classe `Farmer`**, ou seja, ela tem o `set` privado.

A ideia então, é receber este valor no construtor, tratá-lo e *settar* na propriedade.

```
public class Farmer
{
    public int NumberOfCows { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfTractors { get; private set; }

    public Farmer(int numberOfTractors)
    {
        AlgumaOperacaoQualquer(numberOfTractors);
        NumberOfTractors = numberOfTractors;
    }
}

public partial class Form1: Form
{
    Farmer farmer;

    public Form1(int nOfTractors)
    {            
        farmer = new Farmer(nOfTractors);
        /* Perceba que este valor é recebido pelo construtor de Form1. 
           E como só é possível enviar este parâmetro pelo construtor de 
           de Farm, então, a instanciação aqui se torna obrigatória */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No código acima demonstrado, o autor optou por instanciar o objeto `Farmer farmer` no construtor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Farmer farmer;
    public Form1 () {
        InitializeComponent();
        farmer = new Farmer() { NumberOfCows = 15};
    }
}
```

Outra abordagem possível seria instanciar o objeto farmer imediatamente no momento da criação do objeto:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Farmer farmer = new Farmer() { NumberOfCows = 15};
    public Form1 () {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Na realidade o comportamento é basicamente o mesmo, porém é costumeiro instanciarmos os objetos dentro do construtor, para uma melhor organização.

Comment: *a variável farmer está sendo utilizada no nível de classe, por isso não está sendo criada e instanciada dentro do construtor*. Sua afirmação está errada, uma vez que é possível instanciar a variável no momento da declaração. Isso é perfeitamente válido. **`public partial class Form1 : Form { Farmer farmer = new Farmer { NumberOfCows = 15 }}`**

Comment: @jbueno, minha afirmação é quanto ao contexto atual do código, na realidade caso o usuário deseje instanciar a variável no momento da declaração. ele pode fazer isso perfeitamente. Só fiz uma reflexão quanto ao contexto atual. Havia entendido a questão errôneamente, vou editá-la