# Por que imprime o tipo da variável no lugar do resultado?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

Veja o método abaixo:

```
public void TesteLambda() {
            List<String> selecoes = new List<string>();
            selecoes.Add("USA");
            selecoes.Add("Brasil");
            selecoes.Add("Itália");
            selecoes.Add("França");

            // Primeira forma de fazer um filtro usando WHERE
            var melhorSelecao =
                from string s in selecoes
                where s == "Brasil"
                select s;

            Console.WriteLine(melhorSelecao);

            // Segunda forma de fazer um filtro usando WHERE
            var melhorSelecao2 = selecoes.Cast<string>().Where(s => s == "Itália");
            var melhorSelecao3 = selecoes.Where(s => s == "França");
        }
```

Como podem ver as variáveis deveriam retornar um dos valores da lista, mas o que está retornando é isto:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<string>}
```

O que há de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade está mandando imprimir uma lista e este é o resultado que deve obter mesmo. Se quer imprimir os itens da lista, então deve usar uma estrutura que percorra a lista e mostre os seus itens.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var selecoes = new List<string>() { "USA", "Brasil", "Itália", "França" };
        var melhorSelecao = from string s in selecoes
                where s == "Brasil"
                select s;
        foreach (var item in melhorSelecao) {
            WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pxUt6d). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CitwcC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ListResult.cs).

Comment: Onde posso ver novas formas de instanciar objetos ou atribuir valores a eles como você fez: var selecoes = new List<string>() { "USA", "Brasil", "Itália", "França" }; ?

Comment: Não tem novas formas, tem essa. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu ví, você está usando Where, que sempre volta uma coleção de objetos. Como você está retornando somente um objeto, faça desta forma que é melhor:

```
public void TesteLambda() {
    List<String> selecoes = new List<string>();
    selecoes.Add("USA");
    selecoes.Add("Brasil");
    selecoes.Add("Itália");
    selecoes.Add("França");

    // Primeira forma de fazer um filtro usando WHERE
    var melhorSelecao = selecoes.FirstOrDefault(a => a == "Brasil")                

    Console.WriteLine(melhorSelecao);
}
```

Não tem necessidade nenhuma de fazer da forma que estava, a não ser que você precise retornar uma coleção. Se for um valor único, FirstOrDefault() é melhor.

Comment: Foi a nível de aprendizagem. O bigwon disse o que estava errado.

Comment: Sim, mas só um comentário adicional então, não precisa fazer cast no elemento da lista, como em "from string s in selecoes" ou "selecoes.Cast<string>()". No C# String e string são o mesmo tipo, então pode somente utilizar direto ;)

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você definiu como List sendo String uma classe e iniciou como new List(); sendo um tipo de variável.

> ```
> List<String> selecoes = new List<String>();
>
> //ou
>
> List<string> selecoes = new List<string>();
> ```