# O que é MVC (Model, View, Controller)?

Tags: mvc, terminologia, arquitetura-de-software

Afinal, como funciona esse padrão de arquitetura seguindo as camadas *model*, *view* e *controller*?

Comment: possível duplicata de [O que é MVP e MVVM?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21539/o-que-%c3%a9-mvp-e-mvvm)

Comment: @Otto Será que encaixa-se como duplicata, mesmo sendo arquiteturas diferentes ?(por mais que a MVP seja uma evolução do MVC)

Comment: Acho que sim pois tem a explicação delas @Allan Ramos

Comment: mas vamos ver se o resto do pessoal acha heheheh

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**MVC** é nada mais que um padrão de arquitetura de software, **separando** sua **aplicação** em **3 camadas.** A **camada** de **interação do usuário(view)**, a camada de **manipulação dos dados(model)** e a camada de **controle(controller).**

## Model

Sempre que você pensar em manipulação de dados, pense em model. Ele é responsável pela leitura e escrita de dados, e também de suas validações.

## View

Simples: a camada de interação com o usuário. Ela apenas faz a  exibição dos dados.

## Controller

O responsável por receber todas as requisições do usuário. Seus métodos chamados actions são responsáveis por uma página, controlando qual model usar e qual view será mostrado ao usuário.

*(A imagem abaixo representa o fluxo do MVC em um contexto de Internet, com uma requisição HTTP e resposta em formato HTML ou XML)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## O diálogo das camadas na Web

**View** - Fala Controller ! O usuário acabou de pedir para acessar o Facebook ! Pega os dados de login dele ai.

**Controller** – Blz. Já te mando a resposta. Ai model, meu parceiro, toma esses dados de login e verifica se ele loga.

**Model** – Os dados são válidos. Mandando a resposta de login.

**Controller** – Blz. View, o usuário informou os dados corretos. Vou mandar pra vc os dados dele e você carrega a página de perfil.

**View** – Vlw. Mostrando ao usuário…

**OBS**: Este texto foi retirado de meu artigo do site Tableless: [MVC, Afinal, é o quê ?](http://tableless.com.br/mvc-afinal-e-o-que/)

É interessante complementar essa minha resposta antiga:

- No fluxograma feito, dá a entender que o usuário consegue a comunicação direta com o controller, mas não é isso. Através da interação com a página web(view), a request é feita para o back-end, aí então o controller recebe a requisição.

Comment: O padrão arquitetural MVC é anterior à Internet. Tecnologias específicas (XML, HTML, HTTP) podem ser incluídas em um exemplo para ajudar na compreensão do conceito mas sugiro deixar de fora da definição formal do padrão.

Comment: @Piovezan Fiz alterações. O que achou ?

Comment: Bom, View significa que é o visualizador, a visão, controller é o controlador, já o model vem de BUSINESS MODEL, que significa Modelo de Negócios. Seria legal colocar algo do tipo, principalmente a parte do model, para incrementar. Abraço.

Comment: Que resposta interessante. Este dialogo entre as camadas achei genial para o pessoal menos experiente entender. :)

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi responder agora para dar um contraditório. A resposta atual não está errada. Mas também não está certa. Depende de quem está olhando.

MVC é mais um desses termos que são usados indiscriminadamente e perdeu o sentido original. Virou *buzzword* e cai no mesmo erro de OOP, ou de API que é usado como se fosse REST ou algo HTTP, só para citar dois exemplos de uso erro do termo.

O que foi definido nos anos 70 nada tem a ver com o que as pessoas costumam falar que é hoje em dia e que quase sempre virou um mecanismo de web, frequentemente de *backend*. Aconteceu algo parecido com o que aconteceu com OOP que o termo foi criado de um jeito mas o que foi popularizado é outra coisa, ou com API que começou ser usado de forma tão intensa em uma tecnologia que virou sinônimo, mesmo sem ser. O mesmo pode ser dito de "frontend* que as pessoas acham que é só web.

E boa sorte de encontrar um local que diga exatamente o que é MVC, quais são as regras que indicam o que é e o que não é. Tem algumas linhas gerais que as pessoas usam em web, que é diferente de outras áreas, mas quando olha os detalhes, cada um vê de um jeito. As implementações de tecnologias que levam MVC no nome são diferentes demais para todas serem MVC.

Por isso não é mais uma conceituação, uma definição científica, é um nome de marketing, da mesma forma que NoSQL e até microsserviços, como exemplos.

No mínimo deveria chamar de "MVC web" o que usam por aí. Ainda não resolve o problema de múltiplas definições, mas já separaria da forma original do termo.

O MVC começou ser adotado pelo mesmo motivo que OOP começou ser adotada. Tinha um procedural ruim e precisava ser melhor modularizado, fizeram isso e chamaram de orientado a objeto que era um termo que já existia, mas não encaixava no que queriam. Então páginas web feitas de forma ruim (em muitos casos não fazia diferença) e precisava de uma forma mais organizada, com responsabilidades mais separadas, e já tinha um termo que parecia isso, adotaram mesmo fazendo algo diferente.

Não tem mais como consertar isso, então podemos aceitar como uma definição de MVC que é web, mas esse termo fica implícito em quase todas as conversas, e ela é mais ou menos, dependendo de quem está falando, o que a resposta aceita diz.

Se nem o Uncle Bob conseguiu convencer as pessoas que isso é um erro, não serei eu que conseguirei, mas está aí para você pelo menos refletir sobre.

Não que o MVC seja necessariamente ruim, ele é só quando é usado onde não deve. Tem casos que o simples sem tanta separação de responsabilidade é melhor, e tem casos que outras formas de fazer isso são melhores. Os "concorrentes" do MVC pelo menos tem definições mais universais e não sequestraram um termo para si.

Tão pouco estou dizendo que ele é bom, nem mesmo no original, que há bastante críticas que não melhorava o desenvolvimento e até se tornava inviável em alguns casos. Mesmo esse MVC web que pode resolver um problema, causa outros, e quase sempre te obriga mudar vários lugares em cada alteração que faz no código, isso não é bom *design*. Mas as pessoas adotam o que está na moda, não o que ela tem comprovação de ser melhor.

Pesquisando o assunto foi um dos termos que mais encontrei pessoas discordando do que é.

E nem estou entrando em outros detalhes que "ninguém" sabe o que é como "tal coisa vai no *model* ou no *controller*?" E que cada um tem um jeito de pensar, sendo que alguns dizem que vai no *service*, que não existe na definição do MVC, mas usam mesmo assim e talvez alguns mudem a definição dele para aceitar esse novo componente.