# Adicionar Header e Footer em todas as paginas

Tags: php, jquery, html, header

Estou criando uma nova versão de um portal de guia de cidades, existem diversas páginas e atualmente o pessoal usa o include do .shtml:

```
include virtual="../header.htm"

include virtual="../footer.htm"
```

Há alguma outra forma de puxar o *header* e o *footer* em todas as páginas, sem usar o include do .shtml e o include do PHP? Pois todas as páginas precisam ser em .html, o site tem que ser estático, não posso utilizar wordpress ou qualquer cms...  eu já tentei o include do jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 

  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
```

Mas o código final não aparece a página inteira no código fonte, se eu der um <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> pra ver o código fonte, o header estará como `div id="header"` e `/div`, sem aparecer o seu conteúdo no código fonte, isso pode gerar algum problema para o SEO, não?

Como vocês fazem para incluir o *header* e o *footer* em todas as páginas dos *sites* que vocês desenvolvem?

Ah, e aqui na empresa utilizam windows...

Answer (score 1):

`include virtual` é suportado no IIS, mas tem casos que não funcionam em arquivos `.php`, o próprio php já tem duas funções para incluir arquivos, [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php) e [require](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require.php).

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
require '../header.htm';

require '../footer.htm';
?>
```

No entanto recomendo você começar a pensar na arquitetura MVC (Model, View e Controller), leia mais em: [O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/3635)

**Nota:** Não recomendo usar jQuery para "incluir", por dois motivos:

1. A página irá redimensionar o que causará um efeito de pulo no conteúdo e no scroll
2. Serão 3 requisições e dependendo do servidor pode demorar quase 1 segundo para carregar cada um deles o que faria parecer que as coisas estão quebradas

Comment: então, hoje eles já utilizam o include virtual .shtml, porém, não querem mais utilizar, e também não querem que o site seja .php, querem tudo em .html, é possivel incluir header e footer utilizando somente html? ou com algum recurso javascript, não sendo o jquery que já foi mencionado acima?

qual a boa pratica para incluir header/footer em site estatico? somente usando o include e require do php mesmo?

Comment: @AllyssonDosSantos tudo em html? Mas então porque a tag [php] na sua pergunta? html é estático, não entendo como tudo vai ser em html.

Comment: Eu também não entendi o porque ser tudo em html, porém, querem assim... mas então, a melhor opção seria utilizar o include do php?

Comment: @AllyssonDosSantos A melhor opção a curto prazo sim, seria o include ou require do php. Já a longo prazo seria o MVC que é uma arquitetura (um modo de fazer as coisas), veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55486/o-que-é-mvcmodel-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer isso com jQuery. Coloque esse código em `index.html`

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function () {
            $("#header").load("header.html");
            $("#footer").load("footer.html");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header"></div>
      <!--Remaining section-->
      <div id="footer"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Allysson, usar esta forma não causa nenhum problema em questão de `SEO` visto que a página `header.html` e `footer.html` e também indexada pelos motores de busca, e apenas este o seu fator contra a esse tipo de abortagem usando `jQuery`?