# MVC Dao - Como Separo o DAO da Classe Controle?

Tags: java, mvc

1-Meu DAO está dentro da Classe ControleBairro, como faço para separá-lo numa DaoBairro?

2-O ConectaBanco tem o padrão Factory (Fábrica de conexão)?

Detalhes aqui, com os códigos:
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Java/MVC-como-separar-o-DAO-da-classe-Controle

```
    package Controle;

import Conexao.ConectaBanco;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import modelo.ModeloBairro;



/**
 *
 * @author brainiac
 */
public class ControleBairro {
    ConectaBanco conex = new ConectaBanco();
    ConectaBanco conexPesq = new ConectaBanco();
    String cidade = null;
    int codCid = 0;

    // inserir dados no BD
    public void gravar(ModeloBairro obj) {
        conex.conexao();

        try {
            conex.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE nome_cidade='"+obj.getCidade()+"'");
            conex.rs.first();
            codCid = conex.rs.getInt("id_cidade");
            PreparedStatement pst = conex.con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bairro (nome_bairro, id_cidade) VALUES(?, ?)");
            pst.setString(1, obj.getNome());
            pst.setInt(2, codCid);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserido com sucesso pela Camada Controle");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não Inserido  pela Camada Controle!"+ex);
        }
        conex.desconecta();



    }

    // Botão Primeiro
    public ModeloBairro primeiro() {
        conex.conexao();
        ModeloBairro modBairro = new ModeloBairro();
        conexPesq.conexao();
        conex.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM bairro");
        try {
            conex.rs.first();
            conexPesq.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE id_cidade=" +conex.rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
            conexPesq.rs.first();
            cidade = conexPesq.rs.getString("nome_cidade");
            modBairro.setCod(conex.rs.getInt("id_bairro"));
            modBairro.setNome(conex.rs.getString("nome_bairro"));
            modBairro.setCidade(cidade);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao mostrar dados na  Camada Controle!"+ex);
        }
        conex.desconecta();
        conexPesq.desconecta();
        return modBairro;

    }

    // Botão anterior
    public ModeloBairro anterior() {
        conex.conexao();
        ModeloBairro modBairro = new ModeloBairro();
        conexPesq.conexao();

        try {
            conex.rs.previous();
            conexPesq.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE id_cidade=" +conex.rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
            conexPesq.rs.first();
            cidade = conexPesq.rs.getString("nome_cidade");
            modBairro.setCod(conex.rs.getInt("id_bairro"));
            modBairro.setNome(conex.rs.getString("nome_bairro"));
            modBairro.setCidade(cidade);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao mostrar dados na  Camada Controle!"+ex);
        }

        conexPesq.desconecta();
        return modBairro;

    }

    // botão próximo
    public ModeloBairro proximo() {
        conex.conexao();
        ModeloBairro modBairro = new ModeloBairro();
        conexPesq.conexao();

        try {
            conex.rs.next();
            conexPesq.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE id_cidade=" +conex.rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
            conexPesq.rs.first();
            cidade = conexPesq.rs.getString("nome_cidade");
            modBairro.setCod(conex.rs.getInt("id_bairro"));
            modBairro.setNome(conex.rs.getString("nome_bairro"));
            modBairro.setCidade(cidade);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao mostrar dados na  Camada Controle!"+ex);
        }

        conexPesq.desconecta();
        return modBairro;

    }

    // botão último
    public ModeloBairro ultimo() {
        conex.conexao();
        ModeloBairro modBairro = new ModeloBairro();
        conexPesq.conexao();
        conex.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM bairro");
        try {
            conex.rs.last();
            conexPesq.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE id_cidade=" +conex.rs.getInt("id_cidade"));
            conexPesq.rs.first();
            cidade = conexPesq.rs.getString("nome_cidade");
            modBairro.setCod(conex.rs.getInt("id_bairro"));
            modBairro.setNome(conex.rs.getString("nome_bairro"));
            modBairro.setCidade(cidade);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao mostrar dados na  Camada Controle!"+ex);
        }
        conex.desconecta();
        conexPesq.desconecta();
        return modBairro;

    }




    //Alterar dado no BD
   //Alterar dado no BD
    public void editar(ModeloBairro obj) {
        conex.conexao();
        conexPesq.conexao();
       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj.getCod_estado());
        try {
            conexPesq.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE nome_cidade="+obj.getNome());
            conexPesq.rs.first();
            codCid= conex.rs.getInt("id_cidade");
            PreparedStatement pst= conex.con.prepareStatement("UPDATE bairro SET nome_bairro=?, id_cidade=? WHERE id_bairro=?");
            pst.setString(1, obj.getNome());
            pst.setInt(2, codCid);
            pst.setInt(3, obj.getCod());
            pst.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados Editados com sucesso pela Camada Controle!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados não Editados com sucesso pela Camada Controle!");
        }
        conex.desconecta();
        conexPesq.desconecta();
    }

     public void excluir(ModeloBairro obj) {
        conex.conexao();
        conexPesq.conexao();
       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj.getCod_estado());
        try {

            PreparedStatement pst= conex.con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM bairro  WHERE id_bairro=?");
            pst.setInt(1, obj.getCod());
            pst.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados Excluídos com sucesso pela Camada Controle!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados não Excluídos com sucesso pela Camada Controle!");
        }
        conex.desconecta();
        conexPesq.desconecta();
    }


}// fim
```

Conexão

```
package Conexao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConectaBanco {

    // importar com opçãp java.sql
    public Statement stm;  // responsável porpreparar e realizar pesquiss no BD
    public ResultSet rs;   // resp. por armazenar o resultado de uma pesquisa passada para o Statement
    public Connection con;  // resp. por 

    private String DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";  // Responsável por identificar o srviço de BD
    private String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sist_estoq_venda"; // resp. por setar o local do BD
    private String USER = "postgres";
    private String PASS = "123";  // resp. por realizar a conexaão com o BD

    // Paraconectar com outro servidor devee-se mudar os valores declados como privados acima

    public void conexao(){ // Método responsável por realizaar a conxão com o BD

        try {   // tentativa inicial
            System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", DRIVER);  // seta  a propriedade do driver de conexão
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com sucesso!");// realiza a conexã o com o BD
        } catch (SQLException ex) {  // exceção, caso o try falhe cai aqui
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro de conexão\n Erro: " +ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void executaSQL(String sql){
        try {
            stm = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
             rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro NO EXECUTAsql() \n Erro: " +ex.getMessage());

        }
    }

    public void desconecta(){ // Método para fechara a conexão com o BD
        try {
            con.close();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexão fechada com sucesso!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fechara conexão \n Erro: " +ex.getMessage());
        }

    }



}
```

package modelo;

```
/**
 *
 * @author brainiac
 */
public class ModeloBairro {
    private int cod;
    private String nome;
    private String cidade;


    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(int cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }




}
```

package visao;

```
import Conexao.ConectaBanco;
import Controle.ControleBairro;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import modelo.ModeloBairro;
import modelo.ModeloTabela;

/**
 *
 * @author brainiac
 */
public class FrmBairros extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ConectaBanco conectaBairro = new ConectaBanco();

    ModeloBairro modeloBairro = new ModeloBairro();
    ControleBairro controleBairro = new ControleBairro();
    int flag = 1;

    /**
     * Creates new form FrmBairos
     */
    public FrmBairros() {
        initComponents();
        conectaBairro.conexao();
        btnNovo.setEnabled(true);


        preencherTabela("SELECT * FROM bairro  INNER JOIN cidade ON bairro.id_cidade = cidade.id_cidade");
        atualizarCombo();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCod = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtNome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBoxCidade = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnNovo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnSalvar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAlterar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnDelete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPrimeiro = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnProximo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAnterior = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnUltimo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCancelar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnSair = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTableBairro = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Cadastro de Bairros");

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Formulário Cadastro de Bairros", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14), new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.setEnabled(false);

        jLabel1.setText("Código:");

        jLabel2.setText("Nome:");

        txtCod.setEnabled(false);

        txtNome.setToolTipText("Nome do Bairro");

        jComboBoxCidade.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel3.setText("Cidade:");

        btnAdd.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/city.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnAdd.setToolTipText("Adicionar outra Cidade, add another city");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

 private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        modeloBairro.setCod(Integer.parseInt(txtCod.getText()));
        controleBairro.excluir(modeloBairro);

        btnNovo.setEnabled(true);
        btnSalvar.setEnabled(false);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
        limpar();
        txtNome.setEnabled(false);
        preencherTabela("SELECT * FROM bairro  INNER JOIN cidade ON bairro.id_cidade = cidade.id_cidade");
    }                                         

    private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if (flag == 1) { //7:43
            modeloBairro.setNome(txtNome.getText());
            modeloBairro.setCidade("" + jComboBoxCidade.getSelectedItem());
            controleBairro.gravar(modeloBairro);
            preencherTabela("SELECT FROM bairro INNER JOIN cidade ON bairro.id_cidade=cidade.id_cidade ");

        } else {
            modeloBairro.setNome(txtNome.getText());
            modeloBairro.setCidade("" + jComboBoxCidade.getSelectedItem());
            controleBairro.editar(modeloBairro);
            preencherTabela("SELECT FROM bairro INNER JOIN cidade ON bairro.id_cidade=cidade.id_cidade ");
        }
        btnNovo.setEnabled(true);
        btnSalvar.setEnabled(false);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

        txtNome.setEnabled(false);
        jComboBoxCidade.setEnabled(true);
        limpar();
    }                                         

    private void btnAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        flag = 2;
        btnNovo.setEnabled(false);
        btnSalvar.setEnabled(true);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);        
        txtNome.setEnabled(true);


    }                                          

    private void btnPrimeiroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        modeloBairro = controleBairro.primeiro();
        txtCod.setText(String.valueOf(modeloBairro.getCod()));
        txtNome.setText(modeloBairro.getNome());
        jComboBoxCidade.setSelectedItem(modeloBairro.getCidade());


        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        btnAlterar.setEnabled(true);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
    }                                           

    private void btnProximoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        modeloBairro = controleBairro.proximo();
        txtCod.setText(String.valueOf(modeloBairro.getCod()));
        txtNome.setText(modeloBairro.getNome());
        jComboBoxCidade.setSelectedItem(modeloBairro.getCidade());

        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        btnAlterar.setEnabled(true);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
    }                                          

    private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        modeloBairro = controleBairro.anterior();
        txtCod.setText(String.valueOf(modeloBairro.getCod()));
        txtNome.setText(modeloBairro.getNome());
        jComboBoxCidade.setSelectedItem(modeloBairro.getCidade());

        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        btnAlterar.setEnabled(true);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
    }                                           

    private void btnUltimoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        modeloBairro = controleBairro.ultimo();  
        txtCod.setText(String.valueOf(modeloBairro.getCod()));
        txtNome.setText(modeloBairro.getNome());
        jComboBoxCidade.setSelectedItem(modeloBairro.getCidade());

        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        btnAlterar.setEnabled(true);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
    }                                         

    private void btnCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        btnNovo.setEnabled(true);
        btnSalvar.setEnabled(false);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
        btnAlterar.setEnabled(false);
        btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
        limpar();
        txtNome.setEnabled(false);
    }                                           

    private void btnSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        this.dispose();
    }                                       

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        FrmCidades frm= new FrmCidades();
        frm.setVisible(true);
        atualizarCombo();
    }                                      

    public void preencherTabela(String SQL) {
        ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();

        String[] colunas = new String[]{"ID", "Bairro", "Cidade"};

        conectaBairro.executaSQL(SQL);
        try {
            conectaBairro.rs.first();
            // Abaixo preenchendo a tabela
            do {
                dados.add(new Object[]{
                    conectaBairro.rs.getInt("id_cidade"),
                    conectaBairro.rs.getString("nome_bairro"),
                    conectaBairro.rs.getString("nome_cidade")
                });

            } while (conectaBairro .rs.next());

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Erro ao preenchar o ArrayList!\n  " + ex);
        }
        ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, colunas);
        jTableBairro.setModel(modelo);
        jTableBairro.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40); // Width é o tamanho em pixel
        jTableBairro.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false); // não poderá aumentar o tamanhao com o mouse

        jTableBairro.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        jTableBairro.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);

        jTableBairro.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(250);
        jTableBairro.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);

        // chamando a tabela
        jTableBairro.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jTableBairro.setAutoResizeMode(jTableBairro.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        jTableBairro.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); // vai poder slecionar apenas 1 eleento desta tabela

    }

    public void atualizarCombo() {

        jComboBoxCidade.removeAllItems();  // REmove, limpa todos os itens do comboBox, para pode armazenar em seguida
        try {
            conectaBairro.executaSQL("SELECT * FROM cidade ORDER BY nome_cidade");
            conectaBairro.rs.first(); //  para preencher tabela precisa estar posicionado no primeiro registro
            do {
                jComboBoxCidade.addItem(conectaBairro.rs.getString("nome_cidade"));
            } while (conectaBairro.rs.next());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Erro ao preencher ComboBox cidade!" + ex);
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/28595

Comment: Ok, o problema foi o link?  O código está ai

Comment: Poderia resumir esse código postando exatamente o que você precisa. Mas me parece que você não sabe o que é MVC. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55490/7130
Recomendo deletar sua pergunta e refazê-la focada no seu problema. A não algo "Tenho isso, quero fazer isso, faz pra mim"

Comment: Leonan, o Código já está em MVC, mas o Dao está junto a classe controle, só gostaria de como fazer para criar uma classe Dao separada

Answer (score 1):

Boas

Tens de saber o que é o MVC. Eu diria que não o entendes e o que tem cada camada.

O M de modelo, comunica com o C de controlador que por sua vez comunica com o V de vista. O DAO é um modelo claramente.

Nestes casos, o ideal seria implementares uma camada extra para conter a lógica dos modelos. Um modelController.

Um exemplo trivial seria.

**Model:**

-id

-user

-idade

**modelController:**

-getTeenagers()

**controller**

-didCLickToDisplayTeenagers()

Aqui, a vista chama o didClickDisplayTeenagers que chama o getTeenagers que sabe comunicar com o modelo. Claro que os dados têm de vir de algum lado. Nesse caso seria outro modelController que se liga a um webService por exemplo.

Acho que com estes conceitos já te safas. De qualquer maneira devias refrescar os teus conhecimentos de design patterns e não tentares ir buscar código mas sim entender como funcionam todas as peças. Tem cuidado tambem aos anti-patterns.

Comment: Estou buscando o conhecimento, o código já está em MVC mas queria apenas separar a Classe Dao, que no código atual está dentro do controle.