# Como utilizar o padrão de desenvolvimento MVC?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software

O MVC é um modelo de arquitetura de software, é dividido em três camadas e cada uma com sua função, a minha duvida seria o seguinte, é o programador que cria toda essa estrutura ou é preciso baixá-lo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De forma geral é o programador que cria. Claro que pode existir algo que facilite, pode ter um *framework* que já dê a base e o programador só precisa fazer a parte específica do sistema. De fato existem diversos *frameworks* no mercado para todas as linguagens, e sem um se torna um trabalho um pouco pesado para fazer MVC.

Ele é meio que uma receita de bolo. Não existe uma única forma de fazer, mas tem algumas [características que devem sempre estar presentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/101).

Então faz sentido baixar um [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) de MVC, mas não o MVC em si.

Se não usar direito ele pode ser um fardo desnecessário.

Comment: Ok Muito obrigada vou criar o meu então.