# Qual a melhor forma de passar dados entre arquivos php

Tags: php, controller, organização-de-projeto

Qual é a melhor maneira de passar dados entre back-end e front-end, por exemplo, envio um formulário para o back-end, ele executa um script SQL e retorna um array de dados que devem ser mostrados, qual a melhor forma de passar esses dados para o front-end?

formulario.php:

```
<form action='./back.php'>
    <input type='text' name='teste'>
    <input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
</form>
```

back.php:

```
$con = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");
$res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna = '$nome'");
$array = $res->fetch_all();
```

Como passar o `$array` para o front-end, já imaginava que sessões não era a melhor escolha

Comment: Nos seus comentários você refuta todas as respostas. Isso é sinal de que a sua pergunta não está clara. Como funcionam esses seus controllers? Quando se diz "controller" todo mundo pensa em MVC e na função que eles têm nesse padrão. Você não diz a função dos controllers na sua aplicação, e por que eles precisam se comunicar entre si – o que aliás é bem incomum em controllers "tradicionais". Explique também sobre as views e como são carregadas.

Comment: Já te adianto que usar sessões pra tudo como você parece está fazendo é a pior solução possível.

Comment: @bfavaretto por isso fiz essa pergunta

Comment: @bfavaretto reformulei a pergunta espero que tenha ficado mais claro

Comment: Estou revertendo sua edição porque a pergunta ficou mais ampla, e invalidou as respostas anteriores.

Comment: Eu não faço idéia do que é "passar dados entre arquivos". Que tipo de dados, que tipo de arquivos? Seria bom descrever um cenário real. "Passar dados entre arquivos PHP" normalmente nem se faz. O que se faz é de HTML pra PHP e vice versa. De PHP pra PHP você faz include, geralmente, ou salva em algum lugar (e é atípico, de qualquer forma). A pergunta definitivamente não está clara. Sugeriria exemplos práticos, para termos como ajudar.

Comment: @Bacco realmente. Eu apaguei minha resposta pois eu posso ter interpretado errado. A pergunta está ampla.

Comment: Outra coisa. Acho que pedir a MELHOR forma vira uma questao de opiniao muitas vezes, pois em programaçao, muitas vezes, tem várias formas de fazer. Seria interessante pedir sugestões como @bacco disse. A melhor forma, quem vai identificar, é vc. Pois é vc que conhece o projeto.

Comment: Vc tem algum código que vc já fez? Pode ser que fique mais claro.

Comment: @bfavaretto atualizei a pergunta, acredito que minha dúvida esteja mais clara agora

Comment: Já que boa parte da pergunta está riscada, foi remover isso que você mesmo considerou como importante. Caso discorde, só desfazer ;-) De toda sorte, você ganha visibilidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua arquitetura está uma bagunça!

Vamos por partes, antes, entendendo de HTTP:

1. o cliente faz uma requisição
2. o servidor recebe essa requisição
3. o servidor processa essa requisição
4. ... ainda processando...
5. o servidor responde com dados
6. o cliente faz o download da requisição
7. se for um *browser* que estiver recebendo HTML, o cliente renderiza

Assim sendo, o seu processamento é livre. E como você faz o processamento? Você disse que quer "*passar de um arquivo PHP para outro arquivo PHP*", o que a fundo não faz exatamente sentido... Arquivos PHP não foram feitos para falarem-se um com o outro do jeito que você indicou. Parece até que você queria que um arquivo fosse executado, voltasse para o cliente e esse, então, fizesse uma requisição logo em seguida para resgatar os dados obtidos pelo script anterior. Pelo menos foi assim que eu entendi sua fala.

Normalmente o que se faz é criar uma coleção de funções em um arquivo mais voltado ao trabalho de *backend* e, no arquivo mais voltado ao *frontend*, chamar essas tais funções e exibi-las corretamente. Para tal, você não precisa separar lindamente em todas as camadas do MVC.

Por exemplo, essa separação de obtenção de dados do banco e, então, de exibição foi feito [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286817/64969):

1. a [resposta original do @Sveen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286822/64969) usou-se do princípio de separação de interface e banco
2. a [minha repsosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286826/64969) (que é uma variação da reposta do @Sveen, como eu indiquei no texto) apenas dá um ar de manutenção mais fácil; transformei um uso de inclusão de arquivos em chamada de função

Como a única diferença entre as duas respostas foi que eu usei uma função, vou focar na repsosta original, a do @Sveen. A ideia aqui foi:

1. isolar em um componente a exibição de uma linha do banco
2. no *frontend*, primeiro fazer a declaração básica independente dos dados do banco
3. então, no miolo do *frontend*, obter as diversas linhas e, para cada uma, chamar o exibidor de linhas

Adaptando para o seu caso, poderia ser algo assim:

**back.php**:

```
<?php
function obter_linhas($nome) {
  $con = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");
  $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna = '$nome'");
  return $res->fetch_all();
}
?>
```

**front.php**:

```
<?php include_onde 'back.php' ?>
<html>
  <body>
     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
     <?php
       foreach (obter_linhas($_GET['nome'] as $linha) {
         echo "<li>Olha a primeira posição do array: ".$linha[0]."</li>";
       } 
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pronto. Fizemos a visualização dos dados de maneira independente da obtenção. De certa forma, separamos o "*front*" e o "*back*".

---

Sobre a bagunça... o uso *aparente* se assemelha muito a algo que seria uma página adaptativa. Então, nesse caso, você não necessitaria de submeter a página para uma recarga completa. Uma recarga assíncrona da parte minimamente necessário seria o suficiente. Por exemplo, você poderia separar uma `<div>` para os seus resultados e, quando for resgatar os valores, escrever nessa `<div>` (inclusive descartando os valores anteriores).

Usando esse tipo de pensamento, você pode ter interfaces que exibem informações novas sem precisar de um carregamento completo da página:

[image: exemplo de AJAX da wikipedia]

Para isso, você precisaria enviar os dados (os dados mesmo, não a exibição deles; normalmente se costuma transferir em `json` ou `xml` esses dados) a partir de um *endpoint* PHP. No lado do cliente, o JavaScript se encarregaria de receber esses dados, interpretar e então exibi-los da maneira mais adequada possível.

Você vai encontrar mais sobre essa requisição parcial de dados pesquisando sobre AJAX. Por sinal, esse acrônimo significa (ou significava nas origens):

> **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML

Em tradução livre:

> JavaScript e XML assíncronos

Aqui, *assíncrono* quer dizer que o script chamará um *endpoint* no servidor e ele responderá quando der, não tendo garantia de quando isso ocorre. JavaScript é a linguagem de programação que faz a chamada e depois trata a resposta obtida. E o XML hoje em dia é entendido apenas como uma transferência de dados, não precisaria ser o formato XML de transferência de dados.

Um outro uso do AJAX você pode ver aqui, no GitLab:

[image: ajax gitlab]

Aqui, ao pedir para exibir uma aba, o GitLab inicia fazendo a requisição assíncrona, então colocando o *placeholder* das bolinhas rodando para que eu pense eu ele está trabalhando. Quando a requisição finalmente é terminada, um JavaScript intercepta os dados e trata de exibi-los para mim da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Me expressei mal na pergunta, aliás muito mal, mas entendi o que quiz dizer, porém não gosto de usar AJAX pra tudo, prefiro que o front renderize tudo de novo se necessário, no caso, como eu faria sem AJAX? Nesse exemplo o usuário faz uma requisição mas sem sair da página e quando tiver uma resposta renderiza na tela. E se eu quiser que o cliente realmente seja direcionado para uma outra página, como passar dessa página (controller, por exemplo) para o front?

Comment: Se você for ver, em nenhum momento eu coloquei código algum ajax. O código todo trataria apenas a separação das preocupações, sem demasiadas preocupações sobre tentar se adequar a um modelo ou a outro. Usei o mais básico do DRY, e nem tentei ser tão não repetitivo assim. Para o caso que você apresentou, colocar mais complexidade do que necessita é um anti-padrão. Você deve inserir as abstrações conforme for sentindo necessidade, e eu não senti necessidade de acordo com o que fora apresentado.

Comment: Apenas coloquei um exemplo, no sistema real é bem mais complexo. Acredito então que eu esteja fazendo errado, o meus códigos estão divididos num MVC onde o view envia uma requisição ao controller, mudando de página, isso não é o mais aconselhável? Em vez disso deveria colocar `include arquivo_controller.php` em vez de passar os dados de uma página para outra? Sempre achei que deveria evitar misturar o front com o que acontece no back

Answer (score 4):

A função do Controller na verdade é apenas tratar as chamadas HTTP para a aplicação. Uma alternativa para você, seria passar as regras de negócio para uma camada (diretorio) chamado Services. Assim você centraliza essas lógicas como serviços, e não enche os controladores tanto.

Voce pode por exemplo, criar uma pasta de Serviços e varias subpastas dentro.

`- Services
  -- Orders
  -- Users`

Eu também sugiro que você dê uma lida sobre DDD, isso pode ajudá-lo a ter uma luz:

https://www.devmedia.com.br/domain-driven-design-desenvolva-aplicacoes-com-qualidade/26116

Eu tenho algo assim, porém feito em Laravel, mas você pode ter uma ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já neste caso, você pode ter uma noção de como organizar o Services:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Use e abuse da orientação a objeto, aos poucos você perceberá benefícios e malefícios específicos, mas de inicio, acredito que esses passos já podem ajudar.

Comment: Controladores também servem para comunicação com banco, configuração de rotas, tratamento de erros e log, entre outros

Comment: Servir servem, creio que não seja uma boa prática centralizar tudo nele.

Comment: Pelo contrário, decentraliza tudo, em vários controladores. Padrão MVC.

Comment: Desculpe, não tenho conhecimento suficiente para explicar o meu ponto de vista, entretanto, eu percebo que é mais 'saudavel' em termos de manutenção, que os controllers façam as tratativas de requests/responses, assim como classes especificas de validaçoes (validators) façam sua parte.. Repositorios, Serviços, Presenter, etc..
Cada um fazendo sua parte, de forma que respeite o que aprendemos em SOLID sobre cada um deve cumprir uma unica responsabilidade.

Comment: Para complementar, eu percebo que o MVC dificulta o processo em aplicaçoes muito grandes, a ponto de ser necessário pensar no DDD, microserviços, etc..

Comment: Dividir a organização do projeto em subpastas de subpastas de subpastas não é uma solução que busco,  dividir de mais as partes do projeto deixa ele mais desorganizado na minha opinião

Comment: Considere que, se você tem um arquivo imenso que faz varias coisas e faz algo errado nele, ao invés de 'quebrar' apenas uma parte do sistema, você vai quebrar diversas coisas. Mas perfeito, foi apenas uma sugestão com base no pouco que estudo.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, pelo que entendi, você está usando MVC (Talvez mudando o nome do DAO).
Seguindo esta premissa, não tem problema você criar diversos controlers na pasta controllers. Na verdade, esta é a ideia.

Exemplo de controller e seu uso:

**Controler *Cliente*:** 
**Métodos:** Obter, Criar, Atualizar

Chamada dos métodos, URL:

- http://localhost/Cliente/Obter/5 - GET, onde 5 é um id de cliente, por exemplo
- http://localhost/Cliente/Criar  - POST (JSON por exemplo)
- http://localhost/Cliente/Atualizar - POST (JSON por exemplo)

Com relação a passar dados entre controllers, na verdade isso não é comum. Normalmente, a view faz requisições para a Controller, que com base nas informações obtidas pelos models, respositories, etc. **Envia** a informação de alguma forma para a View.

> Note, são **camadas**

A forma com que a view passa informações para a controller, pode ser GET, POST, PUT, etc.

Já a forma que o controller passa as informações para a View, ai depende. Pode mudar em cada linguagem, plataforma, framework, etc.
Recomendo ver exemplo em MVC na sua linguagem, no caso o PHP, correto?

Pra finalizar, segue umas referências.
boa sorte!

https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-o-padrao-mvc-na-pratica/
https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-padrao-mvc/29308
[O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55486/o-que-%C3%A9-mvcmodel-view-controller)

Comment: Pode reformular essa resposta? Eu realmente não entendi nada

Comment: Humm, posso sim, mas me indique a parte que tem mais dúvidas, por favor. E se possível, veja as referências no fim da resposta.

Comment: A forma como a view e controller passam os dados de um para o outro não vem ao caso, a pwrgunta não é essa, não entendi o exemplo (lista), de uma olhada na edição da pergunta

Comment: Olha, de fato você não tem um MVC, pela falta do model, mas o padrão que estabeleceu os seus scripts sugere um MVC. Se preferir, DVC (rsrs). Com relação a comunicação da controller com a View, vou poder te ajudar melhor se postar um exemplo do seu fonte. Um controller e uma view. Você pode usar a Controller como um include por exemplo,e usar variáveis globais. Ou até, fazer requisições HTTP para a controller para obter informações (Mais indicado)

Comment: _"Com relação a comunicação da controller com a View"_, isso não vem ao caso quero saber comunicação de um controller com outro controller, passar dados de um controller para o outro controller, não posso postar código

Answer (score 0):

Você deve separar em vários controladores (lembre-se que é orientação à objetos, não estruturado). Você define instâncias e elas terão 1 controlador, cada.

Exemplo: instância perguntas, controlador de perguntas fará todas as operações relativas às perguntas no seu sistema.

O que você procura se chama MVC (Modelo (seu DAO), Visão, Controlador). Use POST para requisições de inserção e GET para operações de leitura.

Se você preferir usar um framework como o Laravel, lá emula com alguns métodos que o HTTP não dá suporte e organiza melhor as requisições como PUT para edições, DELETE para remoções, GET para buscas e POST para inserções.

Use Sessions somente para informações de login!

Comment: Estou seriamente em abandonar OO em PHP, eu sei l que é MVC w não o uso, antes de tentar responder se intere o suficiente do assunto. A sua resposta não responde nada

Comment: Antes de fazer uma pergunta, lembre-se que ninguém recebe nada por responder suas perguntas. Você quer abandonar o OO e utilizar controladores pra que? Queira tu ou não, o que está fazendo é o modelo MVC. O modelo MVC trás organização, se tu tira o OO, não tem nada organizado, só flutuando.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104340/php-mistura-códigos-de-orientação-a-objetos-e-linguagem-procedural#answer-104346

Comment: O MVC pode ser usado sem OO. O MVC vem antes de OO.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam. Muitos Frameworks já trazem em sua estruturas variável global, que flutua as informações entre as camadas da sua aplicação, estude a documentação destes frameworks,que vai lhe reduzir um tempão. Mas existem muitas maneira para troca de informações, seja convertendo os dados para estrutura json com o json_encore para que uma variável em javascript trate da exibição, seja você criando uma função que já estrutura o html em uma variável e você dá um include em uma pagina que tem um echo para está variável se exibida, já que com include variáveis ainda estão no escorpo.

Answer (score -3):

Diante do que vejo na pergunta , é um form para um MySQL, você pode utilizar GET para listar aí você terá seus dados passados por URL onde deverá deixá-los amigáveis , você poderá usar POST para adicionar , PUT para editar e DELETE para apagar , este FORM está muito genérico mas aconselho usar um MVC para tratar entre seu Front-End e Back-End , mas se for só para estas páginas , você precisará ter o form enviando os dados para uma página que validará estes dados , incluir a conexão do banco de dados nesta página e se a validação for Success mexerá no banco, seja visualizando,  adicionando , editando ou deletando.
Aqui uso de PHP e Angular como exemplo:

```
// Incluindo biblioteca e configuração do banco de dados
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config/database.php';

// Retornando os dados no formato JSON
echo json_encode([
    'registros' => $registros,
    'paginacao' => [
        'registros_por_pagina' => $registrosPorPagina,
        'pagina_atual'         => $paginaAtual,
        'total_registros'      => $totalRegistros,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Pergunta muito abstrata , você pode tratar com a resposta em php com json , angular , ver a melhor ferramenta e conhecimento disponível.