# Para que serve exatamente o Model em uma aplicação PHP?

Tags: php, mvc

Uma classe Model pode ser usada para armazenar as colunas de uma tabela do banco de dados? 
Ou ela apenas armazena os métodos para a regra de negócio? Se ela não armazena as colunas, qual a parte da aplicação responsável por armazenar as colunas de uma tabela?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55486/o-que-%c3%a9-mvcmodel-view-controller

Comment: Leia minha pergunta, o título foi apenas para chamar atenção, os links que você forneceu não me ajudam a responder a minha dúvida específica, eu quero saber o que está no corpo da pergunta.

Answer (score -3):

O model é a parte que tem que ter a lógica de Modelo de dados, independente se for uma base de dados SQL , NoSQL, Graph etc.

O model não deve ter regras de negócio , isso pertence a camada controller,  no caso mais simples ela serve como uma representação do modelo de dados no banco, então vamos dizer que temos a Tabela Products contendo as colunas Id,Name,Price um model dessa tabela seria a classe ProductsModel com as propriedades Id,Name,Price.

Num mundo ideal você poderia simplesmente trocar forma de persistencia (SQL, NoSQL, Graph , Arquivo TXT)  e esse model conseguiria funcionar normalmente - mas em geral isso não é assim.