# Como passar dados de uma View pra um Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Pesquisei muito no Google e no YouTube, mas não achei nada muito claro(Eu posso estar pesquisando errado também). Sou novato em Asp.net, e queria passar os dados desse formulário (Trabalhos.cshtml) para o model (Trabalhos.cshtml.cs)
Trabalhos.cshtml:

```
<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Trabalhos" method="post">

                        <h1>Novo<span>:</span></h1>

                        <h3>Título do post<span>:</span></h3>
                        <input type="text" id="titulo"/>
                        <br />

                        <h3>Postagem<span>:</span></h3>
                        <textarea id="textoPost" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                        <button id="BotaoEnviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
```

Trabalhos.cshtml.cs:

```
namespace Elo.Pages
{
public class AdminModel : PageModel
{



    public void Formulario()
    {
        string titulo = Request.Query["titulo"];
        string textoPost = Request.Query["textoPost"];

        StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Mateus\Desktop\Nova pasta\linhas.txt");
        a.WriteLine(titulo + textoPost + "<-- deu isso aqui");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua pergunta tem alguns problemas e como você mesmo falou é bem provável que esteja pesquisando errado ou algo que não existe.

A primeira coisa que você precisa entender é a [Model, View e Controller](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55490/35358). Pela sua pergunta é possível ver que ainda não está habituado a estrutura do **MVC**.

O `form` da sua `View` está enviando os dados para a `action` chamada **Trabalhos** da `Controller` chamada **Admin** pelo método **post**, conforme essa linha:

```
<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Trabalhos" method="post">
```

Ao clicar no botão **BotaoEnviar** ele fará o submit das informações para essa `Controller` > **Admin/Trabalhos**, lá que você receberá os dados do model e poderá trata-los, desde que esteja declarado corretamente.

Sua model **AdminModel**, não receberá os dados diretamente da `View` e o método que fez nela chamado `Formulario()` foge dos conceitos de uma model, que geralmente no **MVC** representa uma entidade do Banco de Dados ou uma representação dela que será exibida no `front end` para tratamento posterior.

Se você seguir [esse tutorial da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) você entenderá melhor o MVC e fará exemplo submetendo dados por GET e POST. Considere estuda-lo! :)